# Extracting the top 5 maximum values in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with one column corresponding to the player's name and the other column corresponding to the baseball statistic OPS.

```
 OPS        Player
    1.000   player 1
    5.000   player 2
    3.000   player 3
    1.000   player 4
    ---     player 5
    4.000   player 6
    1.000   player 7
    ---     player 8
    1.000   player 9
    ---      player 10
    1.333   player 11
    1.000   player 12
    2.000   player 13
    ---     player 14
    ---     player 15
    ---     player 16
    1.500   player 17
    3.500   player 18
    1.500   player 19
    ---     player 20
    1.000   player 21
    1.000   player 22
    0.000   player 23
    0.000   player 24
    0.500   player 25
    0.000   player 26
    0.667   player 27
```

Now, in excel, I need to figure out how to create a formula that returns a column of the names of the players with the top 5 OPS value.  Thus, I would like for the query to return a 5 x 1 column vector in excel.  What cell formula could I use to achieve this?

Also, given that their will be repeating values of OPS, I need the expression to be robust against ties.

Comment: What to do if there is a tied rank for 5th and 6th? The simplest way way would be to set a number filter for Top 5 using the filter drop down menu which will display more values in the case of a tie.

Comment: Can I set a filter using data from different tabs?  My formula is not going to be on the same tab as the data.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Given a data setup like this:

[image: Top 5 by criteria]

The formula in cell D2 and copied down is:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$28,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$28=LARGE($A$2:$A$28,ROWS(D$1:D1)))*(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,$B$2:$B$28)=0),),0))
```

This formula will work even if there are tied OPS scores among players.

Comment: How do I adapt the code if I do not place it in the second cell.  For example, if I placed your code starting in cell D8.

Comment: Change all instances of `D$1:D1` with `D$7:D7`

Comment: thanks really helpful solution. Any tips how to modify this if the players repeat and you want to work with the sums of players?

Comment: If you want the sums, you could use a pivot table on your data, then filter the sum field for top 5

Answer (score 15):

There 3 functions you want to look at here:

- [LARGE - Returns the k-th largest value in a data set.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/large-function-HP010062514.aspx)
- [INDEX - Returns a value or the reference to a value from within a table or range.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/index-function-HP010069831.aspx)
- [MATCH - The MATCH function searches for a specified item in a range of cells, and then returns the relative position of that item in the range.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx)

I ran a sample in Excel with your OPS values in Column B and Players in Column C, see below:

[image: Excel sample]

- In Cells A13 to A17, the values 1 to 5 were inserted to specify the nth highest value.
- In Cell B13, the following formula was added: `=LARGE($B$2:$B$11, A13)`
- In Cell C13, the following formula was added: `=INDEX($C$2:$C$11,MATCH(B13,$B$2:$B$11,0))`
- These formulae get the highest ranking OPS and Player based on the value in A13.
- Simply select and drag to copy these formulae down to the next 4 cells which will reference the corresponding ranking in Column A.

Comment: How do you get around the fact that there can be ties? For example if player i also had 10 as their OPS.

Answer (score 6):

Put the data into a Pivot Table and do a top n filter on it

[image: Excel Demo]

Comment: Can I set a filter using data from different tabs?  My formula is not going to be on the same tab as the data.

Comment: Generally, a pivot table will be on a seperate sheet to the data.

Answer (score 5):

```
=VLOOKUP(LARGE(A1:A10,ROW()),A1:B10,2,0)
```

Type this formula in **first row** of your sheet then drag down till fifth row...

its a simple `vlookup`, which finds the `large` value in array `(A1:A10)`, the `ROW()` function  gives the row number (first row = 1, second row =2 and so on) and further is the lookup criteria.

Note: You can replace the `ROW()` to 1,2,3,4,5 as requried...if you have this formula in other than the 1st row, then make sure you subtract some numbers from the `row()` to get accurate results.

EDIT: TO check tie results

This is possible, you need to add a helper column to the sheet, here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9u_K1HbgiEKbVlad0JBa0ZiaGM/edit?usp=sharing). Do let me know in case things seems to be messy....

Comment: In vlookup do the columns have to be adjacent?  In my example they are but in my actual dataset they are not.

Comment: vlookup works as follows =VLOOKUP(cellvalue,in Range,Column No,TRUE/FALSE)...so yes, you need to change the Column NO (2) in the above example to get the desired result...try changing the 2 to 3,4 and experiment the change......

Comment: How do you get around ties?  Cause multiple players could have the same OPS.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind the case for a PT (as @Nathan Fisher) is a 'no brainer', but I would add a column to facilitate ordering by rank (up or down):

[image: SO18528624 first example]

`OPS` is entered as VALUES (Sum of) twice so I have renamed the column labels to make clearer which is which. The PT is in a different sheet from the data but could be in the same sheet.

Rank is set with a right click on a data point selected in that column and `Show Values As...` and `Rank Largest to Smallest` (there are other options) with the Base field as `Player` and the filter is a `Value Filters`, `Top 10...` one:

[image: SO18528624 second example]

Once in a PT the power of that feature can very easily be applied to view the data in many other ways, with no change of formula (there isn't one!).

In the case of a tie for the last position included in the filter both results are included (Top 5 would show six or more results). A tie for top rank between just two players would show as `1 1 3 4 5` for Top 5.