# Extracting the top five maximum unique values

Tags: google-sheets, max, filtering, google-sheets-query

I am running a Nerf league at a party and want my spreadsheet to show the top five contestants.

Contestants are allowed unlimited entries and only their top score is counted. Entries are being collected on [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/a/cybjam.com/forms/d/1At-jeGoljzjvb9pkByahr2_hJPnzIRKsBf5mojm9-SA/viewform) and The Top 5 published on a [kiosk screen](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DxOAaxbVKATIDvtxgZIHLw6c9xobavp0kJzvVNQLWcg/pubhtml?gid=555769366&single=true).

Here is some sample data:

```
- **Full Name,Score**
- Test Test,3
- Test2 Test2,1
- Test3 Test3,10
- Test4 Test4,3
- Test5 Test5,42
- Test5 Test5,500
- Test6 Test6,20
```

Here is the formula I have so far (with thanks to [tigeravatar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel)):

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$28,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$2:$B$28=LARGE($B$2:$B$28,ROWS(I$1:I1)))*(COUNTIF(I$1:I1,$A$2:$A$28)=0),),0))
```

This formula shows *all* maximum values - if, for example, one person has 5 entries that are higher than everyone else, they will all be counted.

The "top five" must show only the entry with the most points from five different contestants.

What do I need to do to show only the top entry that each contestant has provided?

Comment: In Excel, you could just a Pivot Table.  Drag Name to Rows; Score to Values, and set the Values to show MAX

Comment: Is it acceptable to do everything you need in Google Sheets alone? You could use something like `=QUERY(A2:B28,"select A, max(B) group by A order by max(B) desc limit 5 label max(B) ''",0)`

Comment: Yes I would like to keep everything within the Google spreadsheet. Looks like that formula does exactly what I need! Thanks AdamL!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that the formula offered by @AdamL met the requirements:

```
=QUERY(A2:B28,"select A, max(B) group by A order by max(B) desc limit 5 label max(B) ''",0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
=QUERY(A2:B28,"select A, max(B) group by A order by max(B) desc limit 5 label max(B) ''",0)
```

<= 
It works without a case.

if you have special character in cells in col A, the output/result of function is not right.

For example,

if value in A1 is HN_123_1/2, the output is not right. The special character here is "_" and "/".

Hope this help.