# Google Sheets - how to find a sum of 3 higher values from the range

Tags: google-sheets, formula

how to find a sum of 3 higher values from the range of 6 which are on the one row e.g We have integer values A1:A6 like 2 5 7 4 9 9 It should sum 9+9+7 so 25
Is it possible by any formula or something?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the answer [Extracting the top five maximum unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471972/extracting-the-top-five-maximum-unique-values)

That should provide you with a basic mechanism (`QUERY`), to get the top 3 values. Then, apply the SUM function to that result.

So, in your case, you would want:
`=SUM(QUERY(A2:A6,"select A order by A desc limit 3",-1))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one:

```
 =SUM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN( SORT(A1:A6,1,0),3,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version:

```
=large(A:A,1)+large(A:A,2)+large(A:A,3)
```

to apply to an entire column, though `A:A` could be limited to `A1:A6`.

Comment: This could be further simplified to `ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(LARGE(A:A,{1,2,3})))`