# Using a subset of excel entries for calculation

Tags: excel

Assume that you have 5 cells with values:

```
[12, 23, 50, 89, 95]
```

and you are interested in finding the average of the four largest entries (that is drop 12 because it is the smallest).

I wonder how one can do that in excel?

Comment: Always exluding the smallest value. The you may have more than 5 entries. I just gave that as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the average of the largest 4 from 5 with this formula

`=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:E1,{1,2,3,4}))`

that will only average 4 values even if there are duplicates

Generically if you might have a variable number of values then to average without the smallest value you can use this version

`=(SUM(Range)-MIN(Range))/(COUNT(Range)-1)`

again that will work OK with duplicates - of course there must be at least 2 numbers in the range

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVERAGEIF(range,condition)

So in your case, it will be AVERAGEIF(A1:E1,">"&MIN(A1:E1))

Hope this helps..

Comment: This answer is good. It works well with all values being different. But what happens if you have more than one values being the same? Of course if all values are exactly the same, this is true for the average. Hence for `n` entries what if up to `n-1` are the same?

Comment: I believe that if more than one values are the same, then one of them must be left out. The point is, how to tell excel do that.

Comment: Please see this accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Use `=LARGE` to get the ǹ-th largest value then use `=SUMIF` to add if the value is larger than the n-th value!

In pseudocode something like this: `=SUMIF(data >= LARGE(range, n))/n`, sorry it's been a while since I used excel. `