# Retrieve top 10 results from a data set by category

Tags: excel

The data set I have is for example and the actual data will have upwards of 100 people.  I need to retrieve the top 10 scores from each category in the picture below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1HdU.jpg]

Comment: You image isn't loaded

Comment: This thread deals with the exact same issue:

[LINK][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is really quite simple.

In each of the corresponding cells, use the "large" forumla.

In cell for vertical 1 it would read large(column vertical, 1) - Returning the largest value in the set.

In cell for vertical 2 it would reage large(colum vertical, 2) - Returning the 2nd largest value in the set.