# Extract Top 5 Values for Each Group in a List without VBA

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I would like to develop a formula to construct a table of the top 5 titles / values within multiple groups, preferably without VBA. I have attached an example. Since I am new to this forum and require need at least 10 reputation points to post images, I have uploaded a screenshot to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHIEg.png * Thanks @Scott Craner for adding the image to the post!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHIEg.png.]

I have already discovered and reviewed the following thread: [Extracting top 5 maximum values (based on group) in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823976/extracting-top-5-maximum-values-based-on-group-in-excel). Using the formula I was able to pull out the top 5 from the entire list as a whole, but I have not been able to incorporate an IF clause to separate the rankings by group.

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration! Please let me know if my request is unclear and/or if you have any specific questions. Appreciate any support!

Comment: Which version of Excel? Are you open to using Pivot Tables or Data Tables? The formula method can be a little confusing and will resort to arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Large(If(C:C = "Group 1",A:A),Row(1:1))
```

This would go into the top right cell of Group 1 results(F3?).  It is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

For the Items  In E3:

If the values are unique; No ties:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F3,IF(C:C = "GROUP 1",A:A),0))
```

If there is possibility of a tie then it gets a little more complicated.

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,IF(C:C = "GROUP 1",IF(A:A = F3,IF(COUNTIF(B:B,$E$2:$E2) = 0,1,0),0),0),0))
```

Both are  array formulas and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. then copied down.

Note:  These array formulas will iterate through the entire column, which will take time.  It would be advantageous to limit the full column ranges to the actual absolute data range.  For example change C:C to $C$3:$C$1000, if 1000 was the last row.

---

For more information on Array Formulas, See [THIS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: Thank you very much - Each value will be unique! How would you go about pulling up the title (i.e. Orange, Kiwis, etc.)?

Comment: Given that you have to press [Ctrl-Shift-Enter] to refresh the table, I am concerned that the table will not automatically update as the underlying list data changes. Will that be the case?

Comment: @ndnathan No, The ctrl shift enter is only telling excel that it is an Array and you only do it once. You would copy and paste the formula in the formula bar then hit ctrl-shift-enter instead of enter. It will update as the data changes.

Comment: @ndnathan The first formula will give the Value.  Use of the last two to get the Item name.  If the values are unique then use the middle formula.

Comment: @ndnathan [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) is some information on array formulas.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion ... It works, thank you very much!

Comment: @ndnathan no problem, please mark as correct by clicking the green check mark by the answer, it is something only you can do.

Comment: If there are multiple items that are the same across groups, would it be possible to sum them up and rank them as one consolidated value?

Comment: @ndnathan I believe it would be possible, but that would be a new question deserving a new post.  But before you do play around with the formula and see if you can.  Also look into vba, it may be easier than the long formula this would require.  You could try putting a helper column that uses SUMIF() to sum any like items, then use that instead of the value column as your search.

Comment: Okay, will do! I will mess around and see if I can get it to work first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First, sort the list by descending values. Then sort the list by group. Then use, `=IF(C1=C2,D1+1,1)`