# Excel - extracting top 5 values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to extract the **top 5 players** based on the sales by each employee (without Pivot Table / Auto filter).

Refer my input and output screenshot

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYElg.png)

Any suggestions, how to obtain first top 5 ranks (even if repeated; as shown in the screenshots)

I have verified [Extract Top 5 Values for Each Group in a List without VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909354/extract-top-5-values-for-each-group-in-a-list-without-vba) and some other links also.

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration! Please let me know if my request is unclear and/or if you have any specific questions.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. In your output you have two second ranks, but both with the same name. Also include your own attempt to make this a question with a [mcve].

Comment: Names should NOT be same.

Comment: Tried with VLOOKUP but unable to get the second instance (i.e. if two ranks are same, it is showing the first instance employee name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I use to track the top 5 absentees...
Edit to suit your needs.

[image]

Formula in cell A1:

```
=INDEX(A$13:A52,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$40)/(B$13:B$52=B1),COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)))
```

Formula in cell B1:
LARGE(B$13:B$52,ROW())

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach using **Power Query** which is available in Excel 2010 Professional Plus and all later versions of Excel.

Steps are:

1. **Add** your input data table to the Power Query Editor;
2. **Sort** the table by `Sales` then by `Name`;
3. Add an **Index Column** starting from `1`;
4. **Filter** the `Index` column to show values less than or equal to `5`;
5. **Remove** the `Index` column, then you should have something like the following:

[image: Demo]

**Close & Load** the output table to a new worksheet (by default).

Here are the power query **M Codes** for your reference. All functions used are within GUI so it should be easy and straight forward.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Employee", type text}, {"Month", type text}, {"Sales", type number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Sales", Order.Descending}, {"Employee", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Index] <= 5),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. As you have in your sample:

On Cell `E16`:

`=VLOOKUP(LARGE($C$3:$C$12,ROW()-15),CHOOSE({2/1},$A$3:$A$12,$C$3:$C$12),2,FALSE)`

On Cell `F16`:

`=VLOOKUP(LARGE($C$3:$C$12,ROW()-15),CHOOSE({2/1},$B$3:$B$12,$C$3:$C$12),2,FALSE)`

On Cell `G16`:

`=VLOOKUP(LARGE($C$3:$C$12,ROW()-15),$C$3:$C$12,1,FALSE)`

You can drag it down to get the list sorted.
Hope it helps!