# Get top 10 list with duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a top 10 list in Excel.  I'm having a little bit of difficulty with the duplicates.  How can I have it display the duplicate names for each rank level?

[image]

The formula I have in the Rank Column (E) is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C4)," ",IF(MATCH(C4,C:C,0)=ROW(),COUNTIF(C:C,C4),"Already Counted"))
```

The formula I have in the Order Column (I) is:

```
=LARGE($E$3:$E$3999,G3)
```

The formula I have in the Name Column (H) is:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$3999,MATCH(I3,$E$3:$E$3999,0))
```

How do I get the list of names to display the duplicates?  For example, in order 2 there should be 14 Moves and Dan Galvin; not 14 Moves displayed twice.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Home & Office 2013

Comment: Have a look at this answer, upvote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you trying it using a dinamic table? I use one to get this output, see if it is what you're looking for:

[image]

If not, can you put the sample data here and expected result, tks.

Comment: I have not tried that.  Is there a way to limit the results in the table to only 10?

Comment: You can use the filter option in the first column to get top 10 but it will not take into account repeated values, of course you can just place the pivot table on another sheet or below your source data and add a column with index near it, then apply a filter to that index to show the first ten, it will also affect the rows on the pivot table and you get your 10 values or whatever you need, I know that of course there must be another much cleaner solution (and ellegant) but you can achive what you need only using this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Power Query`

- Sort the rows by rank, descending
- Remove Duplicates (selecting the `Agent` column)
- Return the first 10 rows of the resultant table

The last few lines of MCode need to be inserted manually into the Advanced Editor.  The first rows can be done from the UI.

If you don't want to get into the Advanced Editor, after you've sorted and removed duplicates, you could add an Index Column and then filter on the value.

---

```
    let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Agent", type text}, {"Rank", type any}}),
        #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Rank", Order.Descending}}),
        #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows", {"Agent"}),
        Top10 = Table.FirstN(#"Removed Duplicates",10)
    in
        Top10
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you had Office 365, the `SORT()` and `FILTER()` functions would solve your problem:

Put the rank column next to the names column (now D) and count the duplicates as 0:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C4), "", IF(MATCH(C4, C:C, 0) = ROW(), COUNTIF($C$3:$C$3999, C4), 0))
```

In the first row of the name column (H) put the following formula:

```
=SORT(FILTER($C$3:$D$3999, $D$3:$D$3999 >= LARGE($D$3:$D$3999, 10)), 2, -1)
```

That is, take only the names of people whose count is equal or greather than the 10th in the ranking and sort descending by count.

PS: Those are dynamic array formulas and they "spill" to the adjacent cells.