# Matching the cell (Using Vlooking, index, match)

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have succeeded to make this formula to match the name and date,

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$4,2,MATCH($G$1,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

but I want to make the matching with different row with same name too, like if I enter `2020/8/4` this is "B7" into "G1" cell, it can be shown Lam = TTT99, Ma = UUU11, Co = OOO88

[image]

Comment: Well, you want multiple matches and that can be challenging, so have a look at this and edit it to suit your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: Use `index, match, mmult`. They will help you!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be that you structure your data in a much simpler, tabular way. If that is not an option for you, I have a somewhat more complex array function for you. **This is your final formula:**

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$10;SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$D$10=$G$1)*ROW($A$1:$D$10))-ROW($A$1)+ROWS($B$2:B2)+1;SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$D$10=$G$1)*COLUMN($A$1:$D$10))-COLUMN($A$1)+1)
```

This formula goes into `G2` - you can drag it down to `G4`. I assume that your names are always "Lam", "Ma" and "Co" in the same order. Be aware that this function won't work if you have duplicate dates.

Basically, you still have an `INDEX` function. Both row number and column number for the lookup are determined using a `SUMPRODUCT` function (since this one allows us to do a lookup over a 2-dimensional range).

The first SUMPRODUCT term will result in the row number:

```
SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$D$10=$G$1)*ROW($A$1:$D$10))-ROW($A$1)+ROWS($B$2:B2)+1
```

The term `$A$1:$D$10=$G$1` will check all cells in your data range for a match with the date in cell `G1`. Imagine it will yield the following array of `True` and `False`:

[image: Imaginary array]

As you see, for selected data 5th August 2020, there is only one match. To get the row number, we multiply this array with another, imaginary array of `ROW($A$1:$D$10)`:

[image: Imaginary array row number]

Since only the seventh row contains a `True`, the result of the multiplication will be 7. That is the absolute row where the searched data is located.

The rest is easier:

```
-ROW($A$1)+ROWS($B$2:B2)+1
```

This term will simply remove the first row number of your data range (in case your data does not start in row 1!) and allow you to "drag" down your formula so that you can use it to lookup `Lam`, `Ma` and `Co`.

The process for the column number is exactly the same.

Comment: I'll second Mr. Wycisk's motion to reformat your data if possible.  Something like Date, Lam, Ma, Co across the top as fields and data in rows.  Then a simple lookup or even pivot table options become possible.

Comment: Dear Michael Wycisk, can you explain to me the formula?

Comment: @CodyTong I have added some explanation. But these kind of array formulas are pretty advanced. I hope it will give you some understanding of how it works anyway.