# Using VLOOKUP and not only match on first value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to use VLOOKUP to match activities with product codes, but run into an issue since VLOOKUP always returns the first match. I did a mockup below to describe my issue. To the left, I have a table with activity names and product codes.

To the right, in column G, I want to, based on matching activity names in column F with activity names in column A, assign the activities product codes from column B.

[image]

When I use VLOOKUP, it only matches with the first activity name and give all the activities with the same name the same product codes. I need them to get different product codes even if they have the same name. I want my function to "take the next one" on the list, when the first one is taken.

Should I try to use another function to solve this? Is it impossible with VLOOKUP? My 'real' document has like 2000 rows, and the solutions I found on Youtube was not good to scale.

Thanks in advance. I'm new to here so if I should clarify my question in any way, feel free to tell me.

Comment: How are you getting the data in column `F`? This is a case for a `Pivot Table`. Or if `VBA` is allowed, I would give it a shot but I need to know the table name and/or if this is the only table on the worksheet, and if the data in columns `A` and `B` is values or formulas. If `VBA` is not allowed, feel free to ignore the request. I suppose the data in column `A` is not sorted in your real worksheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding @VBasic2008. The data in column F is copied from another table. Column A and B are values. Data in column A is not sorted.

Basically what I'm going to do is to match the activities in F with codes in column G, then copy everything over column by column into a template and upload it into a system. I guess VBA could work for just 'creating' column G and then copy it over? I'm gonna redo the same type of process for several countries.

Comment: @Vbasic2008 some additional information. I have like 4 different documents with different data I need to match and this is just one of them. So ideally, if a Pivot Table could work, I might be able to create Pivot Tables for future matching as well. I'm not that good at Excel yet, but I'm a fast learner.

Comment: I use this to get the top 5 dealing with duplicates, so you can edit it to suit your needs and if it helps you give it a vote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: Or you might consider using indirect() with the row that vlookup finds plus 1 to continue to the next...

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks but how will the way you just linked work without having the ranking? I don't see how I should be able to "sort" my values as in your example. I'll look into indirect(), haven't used it before

Comment: @Soph test it - and check the aggregate function, one of its arguments is ranking.

Comment: @SolarMike I tried to, but since I don't have any ranking in my tables I might not be able to use it for my issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the raw is around 2,000 rows, you can use a nested index match with helper columns.

Add a rank in column C with the formula `=COUNTIF(A2:$A$2,A2)`

[image]

Then apply the same ranking in your output part as well (Ensure Activity Name is sorted so that the formula works), Output rank formula `=IF(J2=J1,I1+1,1)`

[image]

Formula that lists out the Product Code `{=INDEX($B$2:$B$3190,MATCH(I2,IF($A$2:$A$3190=J2,$C$2:$C$3190),0))}`

[image]

This is an array formula, you get the curly brackets by hitting control+shift+Enter instead of just Enter upon keying in the formula

Answer (score 0):

If you are using excel 365, you can use UNIQUE formula.

```
=UNIQUE(A2:B18)
```