# A counter example for the Unique ranking formula of Excel - Any Idea how to resolve it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, rank

We all know that famous formula for ranking uniquely in excel when numbers are repeated which is:

```
=RANK(X5,$X$1:$X$10,0)+COUNTIF($X$1:X5,X5)-1
```

For instance the above formula shows the rank of the 5th number in a column "X" within 10 numbers.

I was using this and happened to find a  counter example where this does not work for:

[image]

As you can see we have rank 6 twice. Any thoughts?

I tried it again and strangely this time it gives 5 for both B2 and B17 (following image). I have set a workaround formula in the modified column but do not know whether this will be true for all cases.

[image]

Comment: Check out other posts on here, there is at least one that uses the aggregate() function and deals with duplicates.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get 5 in B17 when reproducing, not 6.

Therefore reproducing gives the expected behavior, not what you see.

Check the following:

1. Are B17 and B2 exactly the same? (you may need to widen the column and/or set the format to General to determine the actual values for these cells, not just the displayed values).
2. Do you have "precision as displayed" set in Options?
3. Do you have any settings that encourage rounding results to round up?

If no issue there, try providing your actual precise cell values here (if they differ to what is displayed in the screenshot).

If still stuck, I could dig out some other versions to check. What software version did you see this result with?

Here is my result:

[image]

Comment: It is strange. I have been testing this for an hour and I got 4 in B2, but now in a new file I get 5 and also B17 turns 5. B17 and B2 are exactly the same. set precision as displayed is not ticked. No settings to encourage rounding.

Comment: Ok, strange. I would spend time on well known rather than modified, until the behavior can be explained. Show us what the formula bar looks like with the cursor in each of A2 and A17? What happens if you change them both to literally `=4.3333` (no further decimal places) to test? Also what does D1 evaluate to if you input `=A2=A17` into D1?

Comment: =A2=A17 turns true. But nice idea about no further decimal places. It works now. seems because the number 0.43333333 is irrational and calculated from a formula in another cell, excel can't do the ranking well. I used TRUNC to resolve it and now it's working fine. But still this can be some kind of bug for future excel versions to solve.

Comment: The "TRUE" is instructive, but can still return true if one is a decimal number with many decimal places and the other is a volatile irrational number (like the result of `=13/3`). You could try ROUND to improve on TRUNC, and although both are imperfect workarounds they are probably your best bet with this source data and the software calculation precision (which as you say can be raised for consideration in future versions). Glad you got to a satisfactory conclusion (of sorts); feel free to mark answer if you feel it would help future readers.