# Get values of top N based on sum and condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below table in Excel:

```
Job Profit | Name   | Product
50         | Mark   | Apple
20         | Sally  | Orange
10         | Bob    | Apple
20         | Bob    | Apple
20         | Mark   | Orange
90         | Mark   | Orange
120        | Sally  | Apple
```

As an example, I want to see who of my salespeople have sold the most of `Apple`. I can easily do that with a pivot:

[image]

I am trying to do the same, but just with a formula. Is this possible? Please note, the names are dynamic and can change day-to-day.

Basically:

```
Rank  | Name
1     | Sally
2     | Mark
3     | Bob
```

Comment: I have an answer on here that may help, look for top 5.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't really see it. Can you link to it?

Comment: The search function on here works **really** well, typed in "top 5" and it was the first suggestion. Wow! https://stackoverflow.com/q/58639470/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike that answer doesn't really help me. In my dataset, the names are not unique.

Comment: so use unique() and have a list of unique names that will  update as the data changes.