# function like solver function in excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

Greeting

I have an excel sheet with 2 sheets, in the first sheet name Cost I have amounts in column A ,ID of costumers in column B and invoice number in column C, in this sheet column C is empty.

The second sheet name Max I have sum of group of value from column A in firs sheet(Cost), ID number second column and invoice number in column C , in this sheet all columns are fill.

I need to fill the first sheet(Cost) column C with invoice number for those group of amount had the same IDs and had the sum matched with the Column A from second sheet(Max).

Noted that some of amounts have 60 field(had the same IDs) every 10 amounts matched with the sum in the second sheet (Max) column A and this sum have a one or more Invoice number so I need to put the same invoice number for every group of amounts that match the sum and second invoice number for the second group

here is an example :

Sheet Cost________________________________________________________________ Sheet Max

| A | B | C | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| amounts | ID | Inv. Number | Total | ID | Inv. Number |
| 25 | 12 |  | 50 | 12 | 1AA |
| 25 | 12 |  | 50 | 12 | 1BB |
| 45 | 12 |  | 50 | 12 | 1CC |
| 5 | 12 |  | 90 | 88 | 2HH |
| 5 | 12 |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | 88 |  |  |  |  |
| 80 | 88 |  |  |  |  |
| 15 | 12 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 12 |  |  |  |  |
| 25 | 12 |  |  |  |  |

Need to fill like that :

Sheet Cost_____________________________________________________________ Sheet Max

| A | B | C | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| amounts | ID | Inv. Number | Total | ID | Inv. Number |
| 25 | 12 | 1AA | 50 | 12 | 1AA |
| 25 | 12 | 1AA | 50 | 12 | 1BB |
| 45 | 12 | 1BB | 50 | 12 | 1CC |
| 5 | 12 | 1BB | 90 | 88 | 2HH |
| 5 | 12 | 1CC |  |  |  |
| 10 | 88 | 2HH |  |  |  |
| 80 | 88 | 2HH |  |  |  |
| 15 | 12 | 1CC |  |  |  |
| 5 | 12 | 1CC |  |  |  |
| 25 | 12 | 1CC |  |  |  |

I have write this program :

from itertools import count
import random
import pandas
import openpyxl
from ast import Break
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Work.xlsx')
cost = wb['cost']
max = wb['max']


counters = 0
C3 = 0
Collector = []
CollectorCounter = []
work_side1 = []
list_Cost_amount = []
list_CostId_value = []
list_MaxId_value = []
list_Max_Total = []
list_Max_inv = []
list_CostId_number = []
list_MaxId_number = []
```

''' End define variable '''

'''Pull all Data From Cost Sheet col ID'''

```
for row in range(2,1000000):
    Cost_col1 = chr(65)
    char = chr(65 + 1)
    Numb = cost[(char + str(row))].value
    ccol = cost[(Cost_col1 + str(row))].value
    id_cost = cost[(char + str(row))]
    if Numb == None:
        break


    if list_CostId_value == []:
       list_Cost_amount.append(ccol)
       list_CostId_number.append(id_cost)
       list_CostId_value.append(Numb)
       counters = counters + 1
    else:
        list_CostId_number.append(id_cost)
        list_Cost_amount.append(ccol)
        list_CostId_value.append(Numb)
        counters = counters + 1
```

'''End of Pull Data from Cost Sheet col ID'''

'''Pull all Data From Max Sheet col ID'''

```
counters = 0
for row in range(2,1000000):
    char = chr(65 + 1)
    char_maxcol3 = chr(65 + 2)
    max_col1 = chr(65)
    Numb = max[char + str(row)].value
    maxccol = max[max_col1 + str(row)].value
    maxcol3 = max[char_maxcol3 + str(row)].value
    id_max = max[char + str(row)]
    if Numb == None:
        break
    if list_MaxId_value == []:
       list_MaxId_number.append(id_max)
       list_Max_Total.append(maxccol)
       list_Max_inv.append(maxcol3)
       list_MaxId_value.append(Numb)
       list_MaxId_number.append(id_max)
       counters = counters + 1
    else:
        list_Max_Total.append(maxccol)
        list_MaxId_value.append(Numb)
        list_Max_inv.append(maxcol3)
        list_MaxId_number.append(id_max)
        counters = counters + 1
```

'''End of Pull Data from Max Sheet col ID'''

''' Processing '''

```
for catch in range(0,len(list_MaxId_value)):
    char = chr(65)
    C1 = 0
    C2 = 0
    St = 0
    SumCost = 0.0
    Taken_Max_Total = 0.0
    Taken_ID_Max = list_MaxId_value[catch]
    Taken_Inv_Max = list_Max_inv[catch]
    Taken_Max_Total = list_Max_Total[catch]
    print(Taken_Max_Total)
   
    for il in range(0,len(list_CostId_value)):
        if Taken_ID_Max == list_CostId_value[il]:
            work_side1.append(list_Cost_amount[il])
            C1+=1
               
    while(St != 1):
        
        if (SumCost + work_side1[C2]) < Taken_Max_Total:
              print(work_side1[C2])
              SumCost = work_side1[C2]   + SumCost
              Collector.append(C2)
            
        if SumCost > Taken_Max_Total:
              print(SumCost)
              C2 = random.randint(1,(len(work_side1)-1))
              SumCost = 0.00
              Collector.clear()
              CollectorCounter.clear()
        if SumCost == Taken_Max_Total:
                print(len(Collector))
                for each in range(0,len(Collector)-1):
                    cost[chr(67)+str(each)] = Taken_Inv_Max
                    print(work_side1[each])
                    list_Cost_amount.remove(work_side1[each])
                    work_side1.remove(work_side1[each])
                Collector.clear()
                CollectorCounter.clear()
                St = 1
                break
           
        if C2 == (len(work_side1)-1):
             C2 = random.randint(1,(len(work_side1)-1))
             SumCost = 0.0
             Collector.clear()
             CollectorCounter.clear()
        C2 = random.randint(1,(len(work_side1)-1))
        
        C3 = 0
        while(C3 != (len(Collector)-1)):
            if (len(Collector)-1) <= 0:
                break
            if C3 > (len(Collector)-1):
                C3 -=1
            if C2 == Collector[C3]:
               C2 = random.randint(0,(len(work_side1)-1))
               C3 = 0
           
            if C3 == (len(Collector)-1) & C2 == Collector[C3]:
               C2 = random.randint(1,(len(work_side1)-1))
               C3 = 0
            if C3 == (len(Collector)-1) & C2 != Collector[C3]:
                break
            C3 +=1
            if C3 > (len(Collector)-1) & C2 != Collector[C3]:
                C3 -=1
```

''' End of Processing '''

```
wb.save('Work.xlsx')
```

---

but the problem was it take a random number to calculate and compare so it take the sum of all small numbers with ID =12 then looping to find a number that equal to the total (infinity loop),
I need to make a function like solver method in excel ( search for a sum and take all numbers that I selected ).

Comment: I have an answer on here that gets the top 5 (top 3 or top 10) which you could edit to suit this question.

Comment: @SolarMike You could maybe add a link to the answer you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @Ssayan so if your searching failed then here is a link to one version I did, you can edit it to match what you may need it to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not enough , I need a function use to search, calculate, fit the calculation with the number of invoice and compare