# Duplicate values with match and index grading excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was hoping someone more knowledgeable with Excel would be able to show me how to make my grading sheet not duplicate values/names.
Currently my formulas from left to right are:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Overall Data'!AG2:AG120, MATCH(LARGE('Overall Data'!AI2:AI120,'Poster Board'!F7:F9),'Overall Data'!AI2:AI120,0)), "N/A")

=IFERROR(LARGE('Overall Data'!AH2:AH120,'Poster Board'!F7:F9) & "/" & 'Overall Data'!T12, "0/0")

=IFERROR(LARGE('Overall Data'!AI2:AI120,'Poster Board'!F7:F9), "0%")
```

Which displays the below image in my "Poster Board" sheet rank the students with the Large function:
[image: Screenshot taken from Excel. On sheet "Poster Board" cells F7:F9 to I7:I9]

Currently the "Overall Data" sheet shows this as AG2:AI120 which is where I get my data from:
[image: "Overall Data" Excel sheet displaying AG1:AI16]

How would I go about making sure the names stay the same by changing my first formula?

Comment: Have a look at what I did here and give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: Thank you @SolarMike! I'm looking at your response to the question and I'm trying to get it to work, but I have never used the Aggregate function. So while, I'm fairly certain this is the answer I need for my Excel sheet. Would you mind writing out a version that works for my sheet with an answer because I am having issues "reverse engineering" it for my own Excel sheet. Thank you!