# How to find row number of a cell resulted by small function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find to row number of 5 smallest elements in a excel column (to find related content of each in another column, form example names). My data includes some 0 data (whose names are different). For example first and second are zero. The problem is that match function returns same row numbers of the two items. For example, how to return "March" and "sKill" by match and index function in this picture?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried small() ? Then match() for each small()?

Comment: Have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700 and consider using row()

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: You may benefit from Pivot Tables and filter by TOP5 values

Comment: How would you want to deal with six+ 0's in the dataset? It works for a small data set like this, but as it gets bigger it seems as though the 5 smallest elements would all end up being 0s.

Answer (score 1):

In O365 you can use one of the following:

- I created a ***Table***, named it `scoreTable` and am using structured references.

  - You can use regular addressing if you prefer.

***To return the five with the lowest scores***
`=INDEX(SORT(scoreTable,2,1),SEQUENCE(5),1)`

***To return any number of results whose scores rank in the lowest 5***
`=FILTER(scoreTable[Name],scoreTable[Score]<=SMALL(scoreTable[Score],5))`