# Count unique values in a MS Excel column based on values of other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, unique

I am trying to find the unique number of Customers, O (Orders), Q (Quotations) and D (Drafts) our team has dealt with on a particular day from this sample dataset. Please note that there are ***repeated*** "*Quote/Order #*"s in the dataset. I *need to figure out the unique numbers of Q/O/D* **on a given day**.

I have figured out all the values except the fields highlighted in light orange color of my Expected output table. Can someone help me figure out the MS Excel formula for these four values as requested above?

Below is the given dataset. Please note that there can be empty values against a date. But those will always be found in the bottom few rows of the table:

| Date | Job # | Job Type | Quote/Ordr # | Parts | Customer | man-hr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4-Apr-22 | 1 | O | 307585 | 1 | FRU | 0.35 |
| 4-Apr-22 | 2 | D | 307267 | 28 | ATM | 4.00 |
| 4-Apr-22 | 2 | D | 307267 | 25 | ATM | 3.75 |
| 4-Apr-22 | 2 | D | 307267 | 6 | ATM | 0.17 |
| 4-Apr-22 | 3 | D | 307438 | 3 | ELCTRC | 0.45 |
| 4-Apr-22 | 4 | D | 307515 | 7 | ATM | 0.60 |
| 4-Apr-22 | 4 | D | 307515 | 5 | ATM | 0.55 |
| 4-Apr-22 | 4 | D | 307515 | 4 | ATM | 0.35 |
| 4-Apr-22 | 5 | O | 307587 | 4 | PULSE | 0.30 |
| 4-Apr-22 | 6 | O | 307588 | 3 | PULSE | 0.40 |
| 5-Apr-22 | 1 | O | 307623 | 1 | WST | 0.45 |
| 5-Apr-22 | 2 | O | 307629 | 4 | CG | 0.50 |
| 5-Apr-22 | 3 | O | 307630 | 10 | SUPER | 1.50 |
| 5-Apr-22 | 4 | O | 307631 | 3 | SUPER | 0.60 |
| 5-Apr-22 | 5 | O | 307640 | 7 | CAM | 0.40 |
| 5-Apr-22 | 6 | Q | 307527 | 6 | WG | 0.55 |
| 5-Apr-22 | 6 | Q | 307527 | 3 | WG | 0.30 |
| 5-Apr-22 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

To figure out the unique "Number of Jobs" on Apr 4, I used the Excel formula:
`=MAXIFS($K$3:$K$20,$J$3:$J$20,R3)` Where, R3 ='4-Apr-22'

To figure out the unique "Number of D (Draft) Jobs" I used the Excel formula:
`=SUMIFS($P$3:$P$20,$J$3:$J$20,R3,$L$3:$L$20,"D")`
[[image: given dataset][1](https://i.postimg.cc/WbPzGTwF/given-dataset.png)

[[image: expected output][2](https://i.postimg.cc/ydDq3gGq/expected-output.png)

Comment: So are quote numbers duplicated for a reason? ie does a duplicate represent an update or just that a particular department uses that quote number all the time?

Comment: @SolarMike a duplicate of Quote/Order number means on this day more than one team members were working on that assignment of our customer. I shared only the relevant part of the dataset omitting some of the columns.

Comment: So you might try unique() or consider editing the approach I show here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike using function unique( ) will return all the unique 'Quote/Order #' in the entire column. But I need the count of unique Quote/Order # of a given date only. Your other approach seems interesting. Let me try and come back to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try using `FILTER`. You can filter the quote/order #s by a specific date, then wrap that in a `UNIQUE` and further a `COUNT`. This will count a unique list based on whatever filter criteria you need. Something like `= COUNT( UNIQUE( FILTER( range, date = "x")))`