# Excel Index and match formula

Tags: excel, indexing, matching

This is a tricky one.. I have a list of raw data and am looking to break down this data in another tab by formulas. To keep it simple, I have raw data of all equity and list options with its ticker. I am trying to distinguish all equity tickers and put them on another tab. I am running th ebelow formula to populate the ticker but when i drag this formula down, it provides duplicate tickers. Without adjusting the raw data, do you know how I can paste just equity tickers on another tab?

=INDEX('Pink OMS'!B2:B303,MATCH(Sheet3!A3,'Pink OMS'!U2:U303,0))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9O0u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKjVy.png)

Comment: If you have excel365, use FILTER

Comment: little more complicated than that but I appreciate it

Comment: Well, do you use excel365 or not?

Comment: See this & edit to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700 if it helps give it a vote.