# How can I return a minimum value in excel work sheet if the cells containing the values I am comparing , the values were created by a function

Tags: excel, if-statement, minimum

Am trying to return the minimum value of cells excluding zero but when ever I do it using this function, it returns a zero not the minimum
Function:`{=MIN(IF(DW2:EE2 = 0,"",DW2:EE2))}`

The values in the cells are created by a function which is:

```
=IF(BJ2="",0,IF(BJ2="D1","1",IF(BJ2="D2","2",IF(BJ2="C3","3",IF(BJ2="C4","4",IF(BJ2="C5","5",IF(BJ2="C6","6",IF(BJ2="P7","7",IF(BJ2="P8","8",IF(BJ2>="F9","9"))))))))))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiSaF.png)

Comment: Remove double quote from numbers in `IF()` function. Like, change `IF(BJ2="D1","1"...` to `IF(BJ2="D1",1...`

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Another option you can try with existing formula `{=MIN(IF(DW2:EE2 = 0,"",--DW2:EE2))}`

Comment: its Ms.office Profession plus 2016

Comment: So, try the formula i put in comment.

Comment: Minifs() if it is in your version, with a criterion of >0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is wrong, but it might give you an idea.

```
=IF(MIN(A1:A5)=0,SMALL(A1:A5,2),MIN(A1:A5))
```

This means the following (I'm always working from a list of values in the cells "A1" till "A5"):

1. Verify the minimum of the list.
   2.1. If the minimum equals zero, then
   take the second smallest value.
   2.2. If the minimum does not equal zero,
   then take that minimum.

However, there is one problem with the implementation of that approach: I expected `=Small(range,2)` to give the second smallest number of a list, which it does, but it does not, let me show you:

```
Range : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 => Small(Range,2) = 1 => OK
Range : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 => Small(Range,2) = 0 => NOK
```

Apparently, `Small(,2)` just orders the range, and takes the second element, regardless of the fact that it might be equal to `Small(,1)`.

Does anybody know a solution or workaround for this issue?

Comment: Perhaps need to deal with duplicates, something like this may work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike: maybe it's an idea for a new Excel feature: add a new boolean parameter at the `=SMALL()` function, using or ignoring duplicates.

Comment: That would be useful and for large() as well.