# INDEX MATCH Function, sum all fields meeting criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Currently with the function I have, excel only returns the first value it finds meeting the criteria, I would want it to sum all fields in the data column that meet the criteria. Is this possible? or am I using the wrong function?

```
(INDEX($E$13:$AZ$200,MATCH(A6&A$1,$A$13:$A$200&$C$13:$C$200,0),MATCH($D$1&$E$1,$E$10:$AZ$10&$E$8:$AZ$8,0)))
```

Comment: match returns a single result - the first it finds meeting the criteria. So you need a different approach - do a search on here for top 5 without duplicates

Comment: I more so needing to have excel sum all fields that meet the criteria. Is there another function that would do that? below is a link to a google sheets that better explains what I'm looking for                     If you look at the highlighted table on column L, for example: I would like "Travel & Entertainment" to sum all fields in the data table that include "Travel & Entertainment" yet it only returns the first value that it finds       [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GYLqDYy96nH9j7LHxTQJ5JrEjjB2A0U_6y_f_1qljuA/edit#gid=0)

Comment: [`SUMIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) maybe?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad. I tried but just don't know how to formulate the function either, would you happen to know?

Comment: I _literally_ linked to the documentation for it...

Comment: So have a look at this then edit to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700