# How to use TEXTJOIN to combine all negative values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin

[image]

How to text join all negative value references?

Using `textjoin` function or any other function in Excel. (without VBA code)

Comment: Have a look at this and edit to suit - think about how you would control the situation, perhaps small()... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700 Give it a vote if it helps.

Comment: Have your tried something. Like `=TEXTJOIN("|",,IF(F3:F8<0,D3:D8,""))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use formula suggested by JvdV. You can also try `TEXTJOIN()` with `FILTER()` formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,FILTER(A2:A7,C2:C7<0))
```

[image]

Comment: So how would you now sort the output highest to lowest?

Comment: @SolarMike If need to sort then have to use `SORT()` function before `FILTER()`.

Answer (score 1):

So, had a quick play and this works:
[image]

Only did the first 3 but if() and iferror() or isblank() come to mind if there is only one, two etc results to avoid repeating | without names...

Note, the formula shown in C1 should be SMALL(... not LARGE(...