# Excel return nth value from table

Tags: arrays, excel, filter, unique

I am using O365 Excel. I am trying a filter formula. I need to return the next item that matches and so fourth. Currently I get a spill error once it matches once.

ids |   amt 
1099    109917001
1100    110012001
1100    110014001
1100    110016001

Expected
id =    1099    amt =109917001
id =    1100    amt =110012001
id =    1100    amt =110014001
id =    1100    amt =110016001

So id.1099 returns 109917001 on row 1.
Id.1100 should return 110012001 on row 2.
Id.1100 should return 110014001 on row 3.
Id.1100 should return 110016001 on row 4.

Here is my code so far =UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:B2306,A2:A2306=D2,"No result"))

Comment: What is the difference between id.1100, id.1100 and id.1100 ?

Comment: You could edit this to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: @solarMike There is no difference. I want the first id.1100 to pull the first amount on row 1, and the second id.1100 to pull the second amount to row 2.

Comment: So why would you expect different results?

Comment: What different results are you trying to get? You have 3 different 1100 entries. How are they different?

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to loop through the results on separate rows.

Comment: I could comb through the duplicate amounts and assign a 3rd column for indexing if that helps.

Comment: @nobodyever I guess I don't understand what you mean by "loop."

Comment: @servers I want to build a list where 1st occurrence of an id.1100's amount is placed in G5, the 2nd occurrence of an id.1100's amount is placed in G6, etc.

Comment: @nobodyever What is D2 in your formula?

Comment: @nobodyever Because if D2 is 1100 this formula you have seems to work?

Comment: @ServerS Yes, D2 refers to the Id. It works once for id.1100 then returns a spill error

Comment: @nobodyever I tried this formula and I get three values. 110012001, 110014001, and 110016001

Comment: @nobodyever What exactly does the error say? Just spill error?

Comment: @ServerS Spill range isn't blank

Comment: @nobodyever What cells do you have the formula in?

Comment: @nobodyever Because it sounds like the next column over has data in the cells

Comment: @servers I think you figured it out, when I click the splat and choose select obstructing cells and press delete, it fills in? Anyways thanks!

Comment: @nobodyever Yes that error means the spill cells (the next column) are not blank. Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B:B,D2=A:A),COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [ServerS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962249/servers) who pointed out in the comments that it was a spill over on my end:

> @nobodyever What exactly does the error say? Just spill error? –
> ServerS

> @ServerS Spill range isn't blank –
> nobodyever

> @nobodyever What cells do you have the formula in? –
> ServerS

> @nobodyever Because it sounds like the next column over has data in the cells –
> ServerS

> @servers I think you figured it out, when I click the splat and choose select obstructing cells and press delete, it fills in? Anyways thanks! –
> nobodyever

> @nobodyever Yes that error means the spill cells (the next column) are not blank. Glad you got it figured out! –
> ServerS

Thanks to [Solar Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4961700/solar-mike) and [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) for helping too.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I'm glad you resolved your problem.  Comments and thanks should be added as comments, not as an answer.  You'll risk getting downvoted for it..

Comment: Answer field should be left for answers, not used for comments.