# How to ignore duplicate results using INDEX MATCH AGGREGATE?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[ignore duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssHk6.png)

How do I show only unique values from Index Match results? I want T-SHIRT to only appear once on the lists. How do I go about doing that?

this is my formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(table[items],AGGREGATE(14,6,(ROW(table[items]))-ROW(table[[#Headers],[items]])/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($I$4,table[color],(MATCH(table[store],$I$3,0)*MATCH(table[date],$I$2,0)))),ROWS(K$3:K3))),"")
```

[sample file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Avrnc70-waO6ixYU3icfj1cPT7Hr?e=ts4Grn)

Comment: Check this out, and give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: if you have Excel 365 you can use the `UNIQUE` function

Comment: You can simplify the whole formula with the new `FILTER`-function: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(table[items],(table[Store]=I3)*(table[date]=I2)*(table[color]=I4)))`