# Google Sheets: Index Match with Duplicates and Ignoring Blanks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table for translations with multiple texts and multiple languages.

The texts appear multiple times and sometimes the column for the language also appears multiple times.

I want to create a table that will have each text once with one translation (can be the first one that's available).

I'm trying to use an index, match formula but can't figure out how to search for the next option if the cell ends up to be blank.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ShPiCYu-ujhVj8i6CT0ke5tEI5Yigdq7vL12uzG25DI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have a look at how I get the top 5 here, you may be able to edit to suit your needs, also look at unique(). https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this option and see if the order suits you:

```
=LAMBDA(headers,defs,{"",headers;defs,MAKEARRAY(COUNTA (defs)+COUNTBLANK(defs), COUNTA (headers)+COUNTBLANK(headers), LAMBDA (r,c, SUBSTITUTE (IFERROR (INDEX(SPLIT(JOIN("#",FLATTEN(FILTER(FILTER(B5:F,A5:A=INDEX (defs,r)),B3:F3=INDEX(headers,,c)))),"#",,1),,1)),"#","")))})(UNIQUE(B3:F3,1),UNIQUE(A5:A,0))
```

Comment: Works and kept the languages in order which was a great bonus! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given the table in your example, the following provides the required output:

```
=arrayformula(query(split(flatten(B3:E3&"|"&A5:A11&"|"&B5:E11),"|"),"select Col2,max(Col3) group by Col2 pivot Col1",0))
```

N.B. the order of the language columns is different from your example due to the way the QUERY pivot clause works (alphabetical ordering) - I'm assuming this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
={UNIQUE(A5:A),
  MAP(
    UNIQUE(A5:A),
    LAMBDA(
      text,
      BYCOL(
        FILTER(B5:E,A5:A=text),
        LAMBDA(col,JOIN(,UNIQUE(col))))))}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

`={UNIQUE(A5:A),INDEX(BYROW(UNIQUE(A5:A),LAMBDA(ax,BYCOL({B5:C,D5:D&E5:E},LAMBDA(bdx,IFERROR(FILTER(bdx,(A5:A=ax)*(bdx<>""))))))))}`

-

[image]