# Google sheets formula to get the Top 5 List With Duplicates

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to compile a best 5 and worst 5 list. I have two rows, column B with the number score and column C with the name. I only want the list to include the name.

In my previous attempts the formula would get the top/bottom 5 but as soon as a duplicate score appeared the first known name with that value would just repeat.

Here is my data

26     Cal
55     John
55     Mike
100    Steve
26     Thomas
100    Jaden
100    Jack
95     Josh 
87     Cole
75     Brett

I've managed to get the bottom 5 list formula correct. This formula works perfectly and includes all names of duplicate scores.

Example of what I get:

Cal
Thomas
John
Mike 
Brett

```html
=INDEX($C$56:$E$70,SMALL(IF($B$56:$B$70=SMALL($B$56:$B$70,ROWS(E$2:E2)),ROW($B$56:$B$70)-ROW($B$56)+1),SUM(IF($B$56:$B$70=SMALL($B$56:$B$70,
  ROWS(E$2:E2)),1,0))-SUM(IF($B$56:$B$70<=SMALL($B$56:$B$70,ROWS(E$2:E2)),1,0))+ROWS(E$2:E2)))
```

Here is the formula I've tried to get the top 5 - however I keep getting an error.

```html
=INDEX($C$56:$E$70,LARGE(IF($B$56:$B$70=LARGE($B$56:$B$70,ROWS(E$2:E2)),ROW($B$56:$B$70)-ROW($B$56)+1),SUM(IF($B$56:$B$70=LARGE($B$56:$B$70,
  ROWS(E$2:E2)),1,0))-SUM(IF($B$56:$B$70<=LARGE($B$56:$B$70,ROWS(E$2:E2)),1,0))+ROWS(E$2:E2)))
```

Example of what I'm looking for

Steve
Jaden
Jack
Josh
Cole

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0):

You can set two queries like this for both cases:

```
=QUERY(B56:C70,"Select C order by B desc limit 5")
=QUERY(B56:C70,"Select C order by B limit 5")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SORTN()` function like-

```
=SORTN(A1:B10,5,,1,1)
```

To keep only one column, wrap the `SORTN()` function with `INDEX()` and specify column number. Try-

```
=INDEX(SORTN(A1:B10,5,,1,1),,2)
```

[image]