# Get top 10 values in a range, sorted in descending order on one column and filtered by another column in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, filter

I have an excel range (not a table) from which I'd like to extract rows corresponding to top 10 values in column 3 for which column 1 entries are non-empty. The resulting selection will be sorted on column 7.

I've tried the following using `filter` with `large` :

```
=SORT ( FILTER (range, col3 >= LARGE(col3,10) * col1 <> ""), 7, -1)
```

where,

- `range` is the range for my selection: B1:L24. I don't want `col1` in my resulting table, which is why `range` is not A1:L24
- `col3` the cell range that I'd like to get top 10 values from, C1:C24
- `col1` is the column I'd like to filter for empty cells, A1:A24
- 7 is the index number of column I'd like to sort the resulting sample by, G1:G24

Here's the data in Excel, not sure if there's a better way to share it.

[image]

Comment: you need `()`: `=SORT ( FILTER (range,( col3 >= LARGE(col3,10)) * (col1 <> ""_), col7, -1) `

Comment: Is the underscore intentional?

Comment: no, typo: `=SORT ( FILTER (range,( col3 >= LARGE(col3,10)) * (col1 <> "")), col7, -1)`

Comment: Oh and `col7` should just be `7`

Comment: Great, that seems to work! Follow-up question - how can I select only some columns? E.g. only col7, col8 and col12. Also can you post as an answer so I can accept - for other people who might have the same question?

Comment: Use `CHOOSECOLS()`

Comment: Have a look at this then edit to suit, vote for it if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700