# Excel: Workaround for "Filter & Sort Formulas" on older versions of Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, formula, compatibility

I have a mini-project that works on Excel 365 and Excel 2021. However, since the "Filter & Sort Formulas" don't work in these Excel versions, I need a workaround for older versions of Excel such as Excel 2019/2016/etc.

This is the project:

1. I have two separate lists
2. I need to combine both lists into one list (I did that using the Filter formula)
3. I need to sort items by highest value (I did that using the Sort formula)

Here you can find the Excel file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xJQxb0Zz7DYT3DXoA3kp7I5wzmHdAdLB/view?usp=sharing

Here is an image of the project:

[image]

Comment: So both lists will always comprise the same number of rows?

Comment: Ideally, they won't have the same number of rows. But I can work with the same number of rows if you have a solution.

Comment: Consider this, and give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0):

I've used Named Ranges for each of the *A-Name*, *A-Value*, *B-Name* and *B-Value* ranges. In your workbook, for example, *A-Name* and *A-Value* would be defined as `=$B$4:$B$7` and `=$C$4:$C$7` respectively.

I've also made it so that the number of rows in each list can be unequal.

In `J3`:

```
=IF(
    ROWS(A$1:A1) > ROWS(A_Name) + ROWS(B_Value),
    "",
    AGGREGATE(14, 6, CHOOSE({1, 2}, A_Value, B_Value), ROWS(A$1:A1))
)
```

and copied down until you start to get blanks for the results.

In `I3`:

```
=IF(J3 = "", "",
    INDIRECT(
        TEXT(
            AGGREGATE(15,6,
                QUOTIENT(
                    CHOOSE(
                        {1, 2},
                        10 ^ 5 * ROW(A_Name) + COLUMN(A_Name),
                        10 ^ 5 * ROW(B_Name) + COLUMN(B_Name)
                    ),
                    N(CHOOSE({1, 2}, A_Value, B_Value) = J3)
                ),
                COUNTIF(J$3:J3, J3)
            ),
            "R0C00000"
        ),
        0
    )
)
```

Again, copied down until you start to get blanks for the results.

It's possible that one or both of these formulas will need committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` in older versions of Excel.