# Excel Vlookup function to map duplicate and get the max occurence value

Tags: excel, function, vlookup

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Here Table A has values where A,C has duplicate. In Table B , for each of A,B,C which is considered as input  to table A , it should fetch 12,33,14. The table b populates the output by checking the occurrence in Table A and getting the most common value . Here in this example A had 11 & 12. But 12 had 3 occurence.so it's value is 12   Table B can have other values like D or can miss EITHER A OR B OR C. is there any  Excel function through this i can achive. I know if u put count and the sort based on count it will work. I am looking for 1 line function

something like Vlookup in excel

Comment: Have a look at this, may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: There is no need to share a screenshot for such a short data sample, please put the input data in Table Markdown format. You can use the following [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) just copy and paste it from your excel and then copy the generated table  it into the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no Excel version constraint per tag listed in the question. You can try the following in cell `D2`:

```
=LET(A, A2:A8, B, B2:B8, cnts, COUNTIFS(A,A,B,B), ux, UNIQUE(A),
  out, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(FILTER(B, (A=x) 
    * (cnts = MAX(FILTER(cnts, A=x)))))))), HSTACK(ux, out))
```

The formula considers the scenario where one or more values have the maximum number of occurrences, like in the case of `C` value, both values `13`, and `14` are present in just once. We use `TEXTJOIN` to collect both values.

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

**Note**: You cannot use inside `MAP` the `MAXIFS` function because it is a [RACON function](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions) and `cnts` is not a range. We use as a workaround `MAX` filtering by rows that match `A=x`. The approach of using: `MAX((A=x) * cnts)` also works, but under the assumption that all filtered values are not negative.