# Excel - Returning the name of the highest ranked scorer within one of three groups in a table

Tags: excel, sorting, max

[image]

This is probably one of those questions with a very simple solution.

Due to security concerns, I can't go into much detail as to the specifics of my data, but to surmise:

I have three groups of people, divided up into three groups - "red", "blue", and "green". Each person gets a score, and its all contained in a table. I need a formula that returns the name of the highest scoring member of each group (as opposed to the highest score overall), and I can't add any helper columns.

I've tried to use XLOOKUP to look up the MAX Values of each group, but the result returns the first person who matches that score - who might be in a different group. I've also tried to use Index/Match to match the highest MAXIFS score which worked until I used in a table and then it fell apart.

Comment: Have a look at this and vote for it if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pivot Tables to get the output you want:

[image]

Just take fields `Group` and `Name` into rows section and `Score` into values section. Then apply a filter values on field `Name` group and choose last option TOP 10 and set it up to show only top 1:

> [Filter data in a
> PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-data-in-a-pivottable-cc1ed287-3a97-4e95-b377-ddfafe79fa8f)

[image]

Why using Pivot Tables if there are formulas? Because in case there is any tie, the Pivot Table will show up those values and formulas won't!

Just as example, let's say `Collin` got also 46 Score like Arturo. Both of them are the highest value so both of them are the 1st ones. Pivot Table will show this:

[image]

Easy to update and make less errors.

Comment: Yes, a pivot table makes sense when OP is using an actual table =)

Comment: Formulas **do** deal with duplicates, just need to be able to use them, check out the method I show that i linked to.

Comment: @SolarMike Please, post it as an answer so everyone can benefit from it

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns **IT IS POSTED AS AN ANSWER** I repeat the link to it again: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 1):

Try `FILTER()` with few other functions.

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER($A$3:$C$13,$B$3:$B$13=E5),3,-1),1,{1,3})
```

To get all by single formula and spill result dynamically, try-

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(B3:B13),
BYROW(UNIQUE(B3:B13),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A3:C13,B3:B13=x),3,-1),1,1))),
BYROW(UNIQUE(B3:B13),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A3:C13,B3:B13=x),3,-1),1,3))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Pivot Table + Power Pivot:**

Since you are working with an actual table, here is a fun alternative using a Pivot Table with a Power Pivot measure written in Data Analysis Expressions (DAX):

- Select any cell in your table;
- On the 'Insert' tab, click 'Pivot Table' and tick the 'Add this data to the Data Model' box before clicking 'OK';
- Now go to the 'Power Pivot' tab and choose to add a new measure in the 'Calculations' group;
- Give it any reasonable 'Measure name' and in the formula section use:

  ```
  =MAXX(TOPN(1,VALUES(Table1[Name]),CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Score])),DESC),[Name])
  ```
- Now hit 'OK';
- Select the Pivot Table you created and make sure that you have the 'Group' field selected as 'Rows';

[image]

Now we have it, a calculated field using our own measure showing the top scorer per Group:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

When new data is added to the model (or changed), you'd need to refresh the Pivot Table >> 'Table Design' >> 'Refresh All'.

---

**Formula:**

If a formula is a must, then maybe try:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Formula in `E7`:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(Table1[Group]),HSTACK(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(x,@SORT(FILTER(Table1,Table2[Group]=x),3,-1)))))
```

---

**PowerQuery:**

A 3rd option could be to run a quick analyses in PowerQuery:

- Select any cell in your table and on the 'Data' tab, click 'From Table/Range' in the 'Get & Transform Data' group;
- Select the 2nd column, and choose the 'Group By' option on the 'Transform' tab;
- Make sure that you make the following aggregations in the 'Advanced' tab:

[image]

- Now, on the 'Add Column' tab, choose the 'Custom Column' in the 'General' group;
- Pick a name for your new column, I choose 'Best' and add the following formula:

  ```
  = Table.Max([Helper2], "Score")
  ```

If done correctly, your data will now look like:

[image]

- Now, on the 'Add Column
- Click the 'Expand' button (top right in 'Best.Name') and just select only 'Name';
- Delete the two helpers, and you'll be good to go and close & load the query back to Excel:

[image]

Here is the M-code for completion's sake:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Group", type text}, {"Score", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group"}, {{"Helper1", each List.Max([Score]), type nullable number}, {"Helper2", each _, type table [Name=nullable text, Group=nullable text, Score=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Best", each Table.Max([Helper2], "Score")),
    #"Expanded Best" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom", "Best", {"Name"}, {"Best.Name"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Best",{"Helper1", "Helper2"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

`MaxIFS()` to the rescue:

This is the formula:

```
=MAXIFS(B1:B8,A1:A8,"Red")
```

This is how to use it:

[image]