# Top 3 Products Sold with Sofas

Tags: python, excel, associations, analysis

I am fairly new to Python and have been using Apriori to analyse my baskets. In saying that, my team has requested that I identify the top 3 products sold with certain ranges and I am unsure how to go about this considering I only have access to Excel and Python.

My data is structured in columns listed below.

DocumentNumber - This is the sales document number
DisplayName - product display name
MasterCategory - First hierarchy of the product
Category - second product hierarchy
SubCategory - third product hierarchy
Range - Collection name
Quantity - Number of units sold on that sales document
ProductCode - Product Internal ID

The task is to identify top 3 Sofas (Category) Ranges and the top 3 Occasional Chairs (Category), Top 3 Coffee Tables (Subcategory) and Top 3 Side Tables (Sub Category) that these are often sold with.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this with apriori, and I have over 68,000 rows of transaction data with 33,059 unique transactions to scan for the data above.

Would one of you kind souls please be able to guide me in the right direction?

I have tried Apriori Algorithm in Python, but I am unsure that is the correct way to approach this problem.

Comment: So have a look at this, edit to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0):

You can try pandas. The code will look like that:

```
# Load your data into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Filter the data to include only the transactions that contain one of the ranges you're interested in
sofas = df[df['Range'] == 'Sofas']

top_3_sofas = (sofas.groupby('DisplayName')['Quantity']
               .sum()
               .sort_values(ascending=False)
               .head(3))
```

Repeat for the other categories.
Looks like you are studying datascience. You can check [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) for some more problems with solutions and explanation.

Comment: Thank you!! The situation is that I wanted to identity top 3 Chairs, Coffee Tables and Side Tables sold with our Top 3 sofa ranges. Can that be done with the groupby function too?

Comment: As far as I understand, you need to choose top 3 Occasional Chairs/Coffee Tables/Side Tables that have the same document number as top 3 sofas. it should be smth like that:
`documents = top_3_sofas['DocumentNumber'].unique()`
`coffee_tables = df[(df['SubCategory'] == 'Coffee Tables') & (df['DocumentNumber'].isin(documents))]`

Comment: Thank you!! This gave me an alternative way, but definitely guided me in the right direction.