# Count and Sum if Unique Values Match

Tags: excel

Below is an example of the type of data I am working with:

Unique ID: are people
The column names have several different amount of information. On a separate sheet, I have all of the column info broken out like in the "Column Key" box below.

I am trying to get **the Count and Sum when Unique ID and Column Name matches**  in the Final box. The final product should be Unique ID * Columns (196 rows) at the end.

Index Match Match was no luck since blanks were being picked up as 0 but here 0 is relevant. Countifs and Sumifs errored out - Got any tips? Thanks

| Location | Year | UNIQUE ID | 1-2019-01-1 | 1-2019-01-2 | 1-2019-01-3 | 2-2019-01-1 | 2-2019-01-2 | 2-2019-01-3 | 1-2020-01-1 | 1-2020-01-2 | 1-2020-01-3 | 2-2020-01-1 | 2-2020-01-2 | 2-2020-01-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | A | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2019 | B | 1 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2019 | C | 1 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2019 | D | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2020 | E |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 | 0 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2020 | F |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 | 0 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2020 | G |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2020 | H |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2019 | I |  |  |  | 2 | 2 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2019 | J |  |  |  | 1 | 5 | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2019 | K |  |  |  | 3 | 4 | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2019 | L |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2020 | M |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2020 | N |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 2020 | O |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020 | P |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | 3 |

[image: Data]

Comment: If you need to match multiple criteria then sumifs() and countifs(), even sumproduct() can be used. Check on here there are many examples.

Comment: Show what you tried, as that may give a clue as to why it did not work.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for commenting. I had tried Index Match Match but the issue is, it will always find a match so it would return 0 if it was blank. In this model, 0 matters.

Comment: Why in the final table, unique ID are just one time? According to the raw data, for `A` there are multiple columns. Would you provide a sample input file in table markdown format, so we can provide an answer to your sample data. You can use the following [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#)

Comment: Have a look at this as an example of index(0 et: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: @DavidLeal, you are right....the unique ID should be the same as the number of columns....this was just for illustration purposes since actual data is confidential. I tried your link:

I just updated the question with the table using your link. Thanks

Comment: So am I understanding this discussion correctly, that you could match just on unique ID so for A (say) which has 3 columns filled in the count would be 3 and the sum would be 2, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: @AriMonger but the header are unique, so the count will be always one. What exactly do you want to achieve. Please try to provide a sample date that explains your escenario, it doesn't have to be your real data, but something that show your point. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal count is essential to see if a column is applicable to the unique ID/person.

Comment: @TomSharpe Yes, essentially need to match Unique ID with Column Names to get the count and sums of each combination.