# Trying to unique value from multiple value combinations in another column in MS EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this data:

```
43833   N/A
43833   Eye
43834   Multiple
43834   Legs
43841   Legs
43841   N/A
43845   Neck
43845   Feet
43845   N/A
43848   Arms
43848   N/A
43856   Neck
43856   Eye
43857   N/A
43857   Eye
```

I want to

- find the unique values in 1st column based on value combination in 2nd column
- for e.g. if I give N/A  and Eye i should get-
  result as :

  ```
   43833    N/A
   43833    Eye
   43857    N/A
   43857    Eye
  ```
- result should only display duplicate columns for the combination passed (N/A and Eye in this case)

I used if/AND/OR and countif function this but I don't think it's right. I am not getting it.

Comment: Eye has 3 unique values in column A, 43833, 43856, 43857. Why your desired result only only two? Any explanation?

Comment: Have a look at this and edit it to suit, give it a vote :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
=LET(f,FILTER(A1:B15,1-ISNA(XMATCH(B1:B15,C2:C3))), A, TAKE(f,,1),
 FILTER(f,MAP(A, LAMBDA(x, SUM(N(A=x))))>1))
```

You can also try using `COUNTIFS` as follows:

```
=LET(cnts, COUNTIFS(A1:A15, A1:A15, B1:B15, TOROW(C2:C3)),
 FILTER(A1:B15, BYROW(cnts, LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))>=ROWS(C2:C3)))
```

or adding more names to avoid repetitions and the input ranges concentrated in two names (`in`, `lk`) only:

```
=LET(in,A1:B15,lk,C2:C3,A,TAKE(in,,1),B,TAKE(in,,-1), cnts,
 COUNTIFS(A,A,B,TOROW(lk)), FILTER(in,BYROW(cnts,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))>=ROWS(lk)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

If you want the lookup values in a single cell, delimited by `,`, then you can try this:

```
=LET(lk, TEXTSPLIT(C3,","), f,FILTER(A1:B15,1-ISNA(XMATCH(B1:B15,lk))), 
 A, TAKE(f,,1), FILTER(f,MAP(A, LAMBDA(x, SUM(N(A=x))))>1))
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether the `BYROW`/`LAMBDA` construction performs worse than the equivalent `MMULT` construction, i.e. `=FILTER(A1:B15,MMULT(COUNTIFS(A1:A15,A1:A15,B1:B15,TOROW(C2:C3)),{1;1})>=ROWS(C2:C3))`. I suspect there may be a touch more overhead in your version, though I haven't tested.