# How to find difference in row of an excel

Tags: excel-formula

[How to find difference in rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzaBB.png)

For same email id there is different phone number as well as last column different of data. how can i automate this is there any excel formula to do this

Comment: Edit this method to suit your data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: you can try with this link too: https://superuser.com/questions/1266166/how-to-calculate-differences-based-on-grouping-values-in-another-column-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

Another simple technique to calculate the duration between two times in Excel is using the TEXT function:

Calculate hours between two times: `=TEXT(B2-A2, "h")`

Return hours and minutes between 2 times: `=TEXT(B2-A2, "h:mm")`

Return hours, minutes and seconds between 2 times: `=TEXT(B2-A2, "h:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use TEXTJOIN function all the cells on the row, and compare like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|", FALSE, A2:D2)=TEXTJOIN("|", FALSE, A3:D3)
```

Assuming you have only 4 (A to D) columns, put this formula in E3 -
it will compare previous row (row 2) with current row (row 3)

Then you can copy the formula cell to all the cells below