# I need to extract top 250 entries from a column to another column in the same sheet in Microsoft excel? Is there a specific function to do this?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Microsoft Excel: extracting the cell values

I have INDEX & MATCH function to return data but received an error.

Comment: If you have Excel 365 you can use the [TAKE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/take-function-25382ff1-5da1-4f78-ab43-f33bd2e4e003) function

Comment: Edit this to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Select the column that you want to extract the top 250 entries from.
2. Click on the "Data" tab in the Excel ribbon.
3. Click on the "Filter" button to enable filtering for the selected column.
4. Click on the drop-down arrow that appears at the top of the selected column.
5. Click on the "Top 10..." option in the drop-down menu.
6. In the "Top 10 AutoFilter" dialog box, change the "10" value to "250".
7. Click on the "OK" button.

Excel will now show only the top 250 entries in the
selected column. Select the filtered data by pressing "Ctrl + A" on
your keyboard. Copy the selected data by pressing "Ctrl + C". Go to
the column where you want to paste the top 250 entries. Paste the
data by pressing "Ctrl + V". This will copy the top 250 entries from
the original column to the new column in the same sheet.

Note that
the original column will still show all the entries, but the new
column will only show the top 250 entries. If you want to remove the
filter, you can click on the "Clear Filter" button in the drop-down
menu of the filtered column.