# Return Row and Column Values

Tags: excel

all. I have a query about extracting data from a MS Excel table. Is it possible to extract data from a row and column based on the cross-section of each? Looking at the image, the highest percentage has a cross section at Row 2, Column 2, So I am looking to extract 1 - 1 respectfully.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DImdD.png)

I am not overly familiar with Excel, so don't know where to start.

Comment: Hey. What kind of query do you have / are you extracting to where?

Comment: Have you considered index()? you can specify the row and column it looks at.

Comment: You might want to look at this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand which method you want to use, but you can get the value of the cell you specified with the following code by using the built-in `VBA` macros on excel. For example get the value of `A1`;

```
Dim value As String
value = Range("A1").value
```

For finding the address of maximum value at column `A`;

```
Dim rLook As Range, Biggest As Variant, Where As String
Set rLook = Range("A1:Z100")
Biggest = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rLook)
Where = rLook.Find(What:=Biggest, After:=rLook(1), LookIn:=xlValues).Address
MsgBox Where
```

With a for loop, you can repeat how many columns you have, find the max value in each column and compare them with each other and arrange them to find the largest one.

Comment: I first want to find the largest value within the table and then return which row and column it came from. In the image provided. I want to return 1 for the row and 1 for the column as that is where the highest value is.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the maximum amount, then find that entry. This returns the address of that cell:

```
Function FindMaxAddress()
    Dim rngTable As Range, rngCell As Range, dblMax As Double, strAddress As String
    
    Set rngTable = ActiveSheet.UsedRange  ' Looks at the entire used section of the sheet
    
    dblMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(rngTable)  ' Find the max value
    
    Set rngCell = rngTable.Find(dblMax)  ' Find that value in the table
    strAddress = rngCell.Address  ' Get the address of that cell (B2 in your example)
    
    FindMaxAddress = strAddress
    
End Function
```

If you need the row and column individually, use `ByRef` parameters so they can output ("return") the values:

```
Sub FindMax(ByRef nRow As Integer, ByRef nColumn As Integer)
    Dim rngTable As Range, rngCell As Range, dblMax As Double
    
    Set rngTable = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    dblMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(rngTable)
    
    Set rngCell = rngTable.Find(dblMax)
    nRow = rngCell.Row
    nColumn = rngCell.Column
    
End Sub
```