# Find cells references of a specific time range in a column

Tags: excel, time, match

Hi I would like to find the cell reference of a certain time range in a table column.
For example, I have in A1 = 06:00:00 and B1 = 12:00:00. I would like a formula that returns the closest cell to each value in the column of a table that contains thousands of rows of time values.

[image]

the excel file will be a real time dashboard, but I don"t know if using vba will make it more unstable.

I have used =EQUIV(N9;PL_Assy_Press[PL_assy_press_Time];1) and this =MOYENNE(INDIRECT("Assembly!"&O2&O13&":"&O2&O12))  but its not perfect

Comment: Have you tried match(), but will ther be duplicates? Or you might try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700. give it a vote if it helps.