# State Eligibility Worksheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a worksheet where I need to find the number of store eligible for a promotion. Stores are operating in multiple states. Some state are eligible,some are not.

I need to find the store count per state that are eligible.

I have shared the document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uyJ2mu2tManx3cxBfOtFZ0reLQk4GdSf0lu5MoRACMI/edit?usp=sharing

If someone can help me, that would be awesome!

Provide a formula solution to the worksheet and get the formula applicable to the task.

Comment: I would do something like this and give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(H2:H53,lambda(Σ,if(ifna(xmatch(Σ,E:E)),countif(B:B,"*"&Σ&"*"),)))
```

[image]

Comment: How can I update the formula so that if the state has no eligible store it would return 0 instead of blank?

Comment: Use: `=map(H2:H53,lambda(Σ,if(ifna(xmatch(Σ,E:E)),countif(B:B,"*"&Σ&"*"),0)))`