# How to return the top 10 more frequent column values in excel?

Tags: excel

I have an excel with three columns and in the column "id" there are some numbers with some repetitions. How can I get in a list the top 10 more frequent column values ("id" column) in excel?

So far I made this code:

```
 =INDEX(B1:B10;MATCH(LARGE(FREQUENCY(B1:B10;B1:B10);2);FREQUENCY(B1:B10;B1:B10);0))
```

range: B1:B10

but it gives only one by one the 1th, 2th, ... more frequent value, what I'd like is to have an only list with the top 10 more frequent values.

PS: I have a MacOS

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700 and give it a vote if it helps you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel - extracting top 5 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639470/excel-extracting-top-5-values)

Comment: The question is different.. I need only the most frequent in a column

Comment: Which Excel version do you have?

Comment: This one "16.70"

Comment: So I use this method for the top 5, and top 10 and top 15. Returning just the values or just the names as needed. Perhaps you need to edit to suit.

Comment: @LZL Replace `2` in your formula with `SEQUENCE(2)` and it should work, that is the missing part of it. Check my answer anyway for other alternatives, maybe less verbose and more generic than this one. Keep in mind that your formula doesn't work for repeated frequencies, i.e. two or more ids with the same  frequency and part of the `LARGE` output. For example for: `{1;1;2;2;3;3;4;4}` it produces the wrong result, `{1;1;1}` instead of `{1;2;3}` for the top `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works even, there are several ids with the same frequency:

```
=LET(x, A2:A12,top,3, cnts,COUNTIFS(x,x),
 TAKE(SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(x,cnts)),2,-1),top,1))
```

As @JosWoolley pointed out in the comment section, you can use `SORTBY` instead of `SORT` which produces a sorter formula:

```
=LET(x,A2:A12, top,3, cnts,COUNTIFS(x,x),TAKE(UNIQUE(SORTBY(x,cnts,-1)),top))
```

You can also use your approach, you missed using `SEQUENCE` as the second input argument for `LARGE`, but **it doesn't work for repeated frequencies being selected as part of the top**:

```
=LET(A,A2:A12, top,3, freq,FREQUENCY(A,A),
 INDEX(A,MATCH(LARGE(freq,SEQUENCE(top)),freq,0)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The above formulas assume O365, for older versions, you can make the following substitutions:

1. `TAKE(x,top,[y])` -> `INDEX(x, SEQUENCE(top),[y])`
2. `HSTACK(x,y)` -> `CHOOSE({1,2},x,y)`

Comment: Why the extra `HSTACK`, i.e., `SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(x,cnts)),2,-1)`, and not `UNIQUE(SORTBY(x,cnts,-1))`? And why are you passing 1 as the optional *columns* parameter to `TAKE` here?

Comment: True @JosWoolley I forgot to consider when we have an array to sort, to better use `SORTBY` thanks, I will update it.  The second input argument of `TAKE` is necessary once we use `HSTACK` in this context. it is not default to `1`.

Comment: @JosWoolley I would say that for a large dataset, since we apply `UNIQUE` after `SORTBY`, maybe less efficient than the `SORT` approach. `SORT/SORTBY` are heavy process functions, so I would say removing first duplicates would be more efficient. What do you think?

Comment: Agreed, that would make sense for large datasets.

Comment: Just out of interest, have you done any tests to compare processing times for `SORT` and `UNIQUE`? Re-reading your comment, are you quite sure that `UNIQUE` is not itself relatively process-heavy?

Comment: @JosWoolley I did some tests up to `20K` rows, no significant differences, but the thing is that both solutions use `UNIQUE`, just in a different way. I also tested `SORT/UNIQUE` and `UNIQUE/SORTBY` for `100K` rows and there is a significant difference. The first performs better, which makes sense, so maybe the leak is in `HSTACK`. Bottom line if performance is not a factor, then I would prefer your approach since it is shorter. Thanks

Comment: which formula "cnts" is?

Comment: @LZL `cnts` is a name defined in `LET` function not a formula. Check the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) of this function.