# how to create a composite score using excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, modeling

I want to create a composite placement score for each granting institution. I've been working on it for quite a while now, but can't figure how to do this. Ultimately, I want to know the top 25 granting institutions in aggregate at top schools and where they hired from using this composite placement score.

Data columns

| Granting Institution | Hiring Institution | Universities | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 values | 1003 values | 100 values | 100(top) - 1 (lowest) |

I've tried everything, and I'm getting numbers, but I'm getting values for institutes which aren't in the 100 university list as well, making it harder to sort top 25.

How do I get through this? Is there any magical Excel formula?

Comment: This is not an Excel question. This is about building a model from a number of data inputs (including three unknown columns all labeled "values"). You need to determine how you want to combine your inputs for your purpose. For example, are you taking a simple equally weighted average of the inputs? If not, how do you think they should be weighted? This Excel forum can help you build the formula(s) in Excel, but you have to be able to describe the math behind your model first.

Comment: I would edit this to your use, give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: I've edited your question so your data columns actually look like a table. Now those extraneous "value" entries make more sense. They aren't columns as they appeared in your original, so ignore that part of my original comment. But you still need to determine the math of your model before we can help you do it in Excel.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'll see what I can do.