# Excel column values as data headers

Tags: excel, vba

Im pulling this information from a query in excel and i'm wondering how I could make the "First Letter" column values into row headers (dynamically). Is this possible with some sort of formatting or would I need to use VBA?

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: You can edit this to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: Its not very flexible, but sorting the combined names and letters gets the desired output in this case `=SORT(VSTACK(A2:A,UNIQUE(B2:B)))`

Comment: I would use (insert) a pivot table to get this result.

Comment: "...information from a query..." are you using SQL to retrieve the data in a recordset?

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ Yes

Comment: Then maybe you can make an sql to take the result with headers. If you can post the sql string and some data i will try to do it. Or copy records line by line with vba to insert the headers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```vb
=LET(Names,A2:A8,FirstLetters,B2:B8,
UniqueLetters,UNIQUE(FirstLetters),
DROP(REDUCE("",UniqueLetters,LAMBDA(r,l,VSTACK(r,l,FILTER(Names,FirstLetters=l)))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: I did see this as an option when looking online but unfortunate I don't have Excel 365. Good solution though

Comment: then VBA seems to be the only solution or adapting the source query.

Answer (score 1):

I made a Function to read from a column of a sheet the names and a) either return a one-dimensional array with the names having also headings or copy the result to some point of the sheet which you specify parametrically. Names are sorted. You can adjust the details to your needs. As I wrote in the comment, you can get the result with a complex query:

```
Public Function sqlNamesWithHeader(Optional destination As Range = Nothing) As Variant()
   Dim connection As Object, recSet As Object, sql As String, rc As Long, rslt() As Variant, c As Long
   Dim selectA As String, selectB As String
   Const table = " [SHEET07$P2:P18] "
   
   selectA = "SELECT [F1] AS NAME, LEFT(F1,1) AS LETTER FROM" & table
   selectB = "SELECT LEFT(F1,1) AS NAME, """" AS LETTER FROM" & table
   sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [NAME], [LETTER] FROM (" & selectA & " UNION ALL " & selectB & ") ORDER BY [NAME]"

   ReDim rslt(0 To 0)    ' Lbound(rslt) = 0 ==> no data
   Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   With connection
      .CursorLocation = 3
      .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
      .Open
      Set recSet = .Execute(sql)
   End With
   If Not destination Is Nothing Then
      Call destination.CopyFromRecordset(recSet)
   Else
      rc = recSet.recordCount
      ReDim rslt(1 To rc)     ' Lbound(rslt) > 0 ==> have data
      For c = 1 To rc
         rslt(c) = recSet(0)
         recSet.MoveNext
      Next
   End If
   sqlNamesWithHeader = rslt
   recSet.Close
   connection.Close
   Set recSet = Nothing
   Set connection = Nothing
End Function


Sub tester()
   Dim v As Variant, c As Long
   'this way the result start copied at cell R1
   Call sqlNamesWithHeader(Me.Range("R1"))
   
   'this way we take an one-dimentional array with the result
   v = sqlNamesWithHeader()
   if Lbound(v) > 0 then
      For c = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
         Debug.Print v(c)
      Next
   End If
End Sub
```

[image]