# RANKING function in Excel

Tags: excel, ranking

Task: I would like to write an excel function that will calculate the rank based on overall satisfaction score for a certain store ONLY if the sample size for that specific store is greater than 10. If the sample size is less than 10 then the Ranking field for that specific store should remain blank.

I came up with the following formula which successfully generates the ranking but it failed to exclude those stores having a sample file less than 10. I am not sure what have I done wrong. Appreciate your help.

Here is my code:

```
=IF(Base_SPSS!B2>10, RANK(Table76[@[Overall Experience]], Table76[Overall Experience]), "")
```

My excel file has multiple sheets that contains multiple tables which are mentioned above in my formula:

**Table76**   >>> Contains store name and overall experience as shown below

| name | Overall Experience |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 3.5 |
| LMN | 4.0 |
| JFK | 2.5 |
| RBC | 4.0 |

**Base_SPSS**   >>> Contains store name and sample size as shown below

| name | Base_SPSS |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 80 |
| LMN | 9 |
| JFK | 100 |
| RBC | 98 |

Ideally I want the RANK to exclude from ranking any store that has a sample size less than 10. The expected output should be

| name | Ranking |
| --- | --- |
| RBC | 1 |
| LMN |  |
| JFK | 3 |
| ABC | 2 |

Comment: ABC has 3.5 while RBC has 4, why ABC is rank 1?

Comment: So edit and apply what I did here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: I still don't understand why JFK is not ranked the first, it has the highest overall experience `100`. RBC is `98`.

Comment: @DavidLeal.. Sorry! there was a mistake in the column name. Hope now it makes sense to you

Comment: @Mona please update sample data of your question accordingly. How do you expect to handle the fact you have multiple sheets? is it a known number of sheets? Are the values of column name the same for all of them in the same order? Please clarify all that updating the question. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal.. It is a "single excel sheet" that has multiple tables each in a different tab. The first tab has the name and the overall experience and the other one has the name and the sample size "Base_SPSS". The reason why they are not in the same tab is because each one has 100+ columns. I am here just simplifying things by including only the columns of interest.