# Find address of every cell containing largest number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to find the address of up to 5 cells that contain the largest number in a column of numbers in an Excel 2016 and extract it into another column, lets say B1-B5, eg:

```
5
8 ("A2" in B1)
2
6
8 ("A5" in B2)
1
3
8 ("A8" in B3)
```

I've came up with this to find the first one

```
ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(LARGE($T$1:$T$118;1);$T$1:$T$118;0)+1;20)))-1
```

This one for the second cell containing the largest number

```
ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(LARGE($T$1:$T$118;1);$T$1:$T$118;0)+1;20)))-1+ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(LARGE($T$1:$T$118;1);INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(LARGE($T$1:$T$118;1);$T$1:$T$118;0)+1;20)):$T$118;0)+1;20)))-1
```

But continuing that trend does not work for the 3rd cell and so on.
I need to find the address of up to 5 cells containing the same largest number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this method, should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`=LET(x, $A$1:$A$8, y, IF(x=MAX(x),ADDRESS(ROW(x),COLUMN(x))), FILTER(y, y<>FALSE))`

Comment: Great solution!, I think you would need `abs_num=4`, from `ADDRESS` to get exactly the expected output, as it is shown in the question. Something like this: `=LET(x, A1:A8,y,IF(x=MAX(x),ADDRESS(ROW(x),COLUMN(x),4),""), FILTER(y, y<>""))`

Comment: Works well on a different Excel version. The one I have to use, however, does not have LET(), TOCOL(), NA(), FILTER()... Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The following might work for you:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ROW()=1,ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(A$1:A$8),A$1:A$8,0),1,4),IF(ROW(INDIRECT(INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1)))=ROW(A$8),"",ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(A$1:A$8),INDEX(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT(INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1)))+1):A$8,0)+ROW(INDIRECT(INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1))),1,4))),"")
```

**Note:** Excel 2016 does not auto-CSE, so don't forget to accept the formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and drag down *5* cells.

Comment: This works very well with the Excel version I need to use!
Could you just make 2 adjustments to it please because I don't seem to be able to do that - I keep breaking it.

The adjustments I would like are, 
the range of numbers to search through to be T4:T120
and the address of the numbers to be extracted into AA4:AA8,
please?
What I seem to break is trying to extract the addresses in AA4:AA8 instead of AA1:AA5 and searching through T4:T118. I doesn't like not going from the first row.

Comment: @Dzverry, you can use `=IFERROR(IF(ROW()=4,ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(T$4:T$200),T$4:T$200,0)+3,20,4),IF(ROW(INDIRECT(INDEX(AA:AA,ROW()-1)))=ROW(T$200),"",ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(T$4:T$200),INDEX(T:T,ROW(INDIRECT(INDEX(AA:AA,ROW()-1)))+1):T$200,0)+ROW(INDIRECT(INDEX(AA:AA,ROW()-1))),20,4))),"")`

Answer (score 1):

Under O365, you can find the address of the largest value in a range as follows:

```
=LET(A,A1:A8,FILTER(MAP(A,LAMBDA(x,ADDRESS(ROW(x),COLUMN(x),4))),A=MAX(A)))
```

or avoiding a [LAMBDA helper function](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-lambda-helper-functions-lambdas-as-arguments-and-more/ba-p/2576648) and shorter:

```
=LET(A,A1:A8,TOCOL(IF(A=MAX(A),ADDRESS(ROW(A),COLUMN(A),4),NA()),2))
```

Credit to VBasic2008 suggesting the following solution provided in the comment section (it includes taking the first `5` values only) :

```
=LET(A,A1:A8,TAKE(FILTER(ADDRESS(ROW(A),COLUMN(A),4),A=MAX(A)),5))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

If you need the first five addresses, not applicable for this sample data, you can wrap the output with `TAKE` with the second input argument equal to `5`.

Comment: What's wrong with `=LET(A,A1:A8,TAKE(FILTER(ADDRESS(ROW(A),COLUMN(A),4),A=MAX(A)),5))`? I mean, it won't fail if there are fewer matches.

Comment: Works well on a different Excel version. The one I have to use, however, does not have LET(), TOCOL(), NA(), FILTER()... Any other suggestions?