# I want to get the latest date of 2 criteria in the same column

Tags: excel

I want to get the latest date of 2 criteria in the same column

Like if a column has apple orange mango. I want the latest date of either apple or mango.

I have tired MAX formula but it checks for only 1.

Please help me with this. Not a pro in excel.

Comment: Please post six lines with data and tell us the expexted result and also show us your code

Answer (score 1):

MAX() stops after finding one.

If you want more return you have to change your approach, see this as it may give you an idea;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by combinaton of MAX,INDEX,FILTER Functions. Say that we have a table of two columns in A1:B5

| Date | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/23 | orange |
| 1/2/23 | mango |
| 1/3/23 | apple |

Then we can use this formula

```
=MAX(INDEX(FILTER(A2:B5,(B2:B5="apple")+(B2:B5="mango")),,1))
```