# Using VLOOKUP or FILTER to return multiple matches between two workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two workbooks - workbook 1 is a list of digitised content on a server, workbook 2 is the output of a database that includes the content on the server.

Some of the digitised items in workbook 1 contain multiple items from the database within one file. I would like to be able to use the file reference from workbook 1 to search workbook 2 for a list of all the reference numbers contained in that file and copy those reference numbers to the same line as the file reference in workbook 1.

Using VLOOKUP, this works well where there is only one item per file, but fails where there are more than one:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&A3&"*",[workbook 2.xlsx]worksheet A'!$1:$1048576,4,FALSE)
```

I have tried using FILTER but the formula I am using returns a #CALC error:

```
=FILTER([workbook 2.xlsx]worksheet A!$D:$D,[workbook 2.xlsx]worksheet A!$A:$A="*"&A3)
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction :-)

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing, but wildcard operators dont work with `FILTER()` function as you are trying, instead use `ISNUMBER()` and `SEARCH()` with `FILTER()` that said, the formula could be : `=FILTER([workbook 2.xlsx]worksheet A!$D:$D,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3,[workbook 2.xlsx]worksheet A!$A:$A)))`

Comment: This method deals with duplicates and you can edit it to suit - my original works across 5 sheets. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I have had some success with the formula you gave - many thanks. The formula returns results where there is only one possible, but I am getting a #SPILL error where there is more than one possible result.

I was using wildcards as the required text is often surrounded by other text in the cells - perhaps this isn't required?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=TRANSPOSE(
    UNIQUE(
        FILTER([workbook 2.xlsx]worksheet A!$D:$D,
             ISNUMBER((SEARCH(A3,[workbook 2.xlsx]worksheet A!$A:$A))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi @Yasir, this works - thank you ever so much! Unfortunately, I cannot upvote as I don't have enough reputation points yet.

Comment: I have a further question @Yasir:

Where I have a filename such as AD1234 on workbook 1, it is also returning results from D1234 on workbook 2.

How would I make it more specific, so it matches the filename exactly, bearing in mind there may also be other text in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to grasp completely your question. What I've understood is, the search range (lookup range) or the search item contains file names included. You need to filter out only the items from specific file.
If that's the case, adding another condition within the filter function.

```
=TRANSPOSE(
    UNIQUE(
        FILTER(
            [workbook 2.xlsx]worksheet A!$D:$D,
            (ISNUMBER((SEARCH(A3, [workbook 2.xlsx]worksheet A!$A:$A)))) *
            (ISNUMBER((SEARCH("Type_Specific_Filename", [workbook 2.xlsx]worksheet A!$A:$A))))
        )
    )
)
```

Replace **Type_Specific_Filename** with the required file name as appearing in the list.

If this doesn't work, it would be bette if you could share a sample file.