# How can I use Index() Match() for repetitive value in an array?

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a raw-data table on the left, now I want to use function to automatically fill in the cells in table on the right for monitoring the change when I change "VN_Code". However, Match() function only returns first value in the array. As you can see, VN04 appears twice in the table on the left; so, in the right table, in the second cells, the value only return "0", instead of "C39"
=> I want to the cell to return "C39", how can i do it?

[image]

I try using match() and index() function but found no way out yet

Comment: Check this out and edit to suit, give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700