# How to identify rows that share multiple values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset that comes from multiple people who have undergone a credit check through my organization. I want to identify people who have used our services more than once in order to track improvement in their credit score over time. Within my dataset, I have four columns: year that services were rendered, last name, last four digits of the SSN, and credit score. My current thinking is that I should select all rows where both the last name and the last four of the SSN occur more than once together, and then filter them, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I would be looking at something like this, edit to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700 give it a vote if it helps.

Comment: Please familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question to provide information that can be used to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to filter all the rows that are a duplicate with those two criteria, the formula's rather easy (to comprehend):

> =FILTER(A1:C5,COUNTIFS(A1:A5,A1:A5,B1:B5,B1:B5)>1)

[image]

I'm sure I've seen JvDv or someone similar do this but I can only find "remove duplicates" or something like that.

Use the following if you want them sorted

> =SORT(FILTER(A1:C5,COUNTIFS(A1:A5,A1:A5,B1:B5,B1:B5)>1),1)