# How to use VLOOKUP if the look up value appears multiple times, and I need the corresponding information each time it appears

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have one spreadsheet that tracks all the info I need based on job numbers. A job number can appear several times on the spreadsheet with different information. For example job number 1234 is on the sheet 3 times, because work is being done at 3 different locations. So the job number in cell A is the same, but the subsequent information in cells B-I is different.

I am trying to create a second spreadsheet that pulls specific info, dates for different milestones, for each line in sheet 1, to build a dynamic report.

The issue I'm having is `VLOOKUP` just searches for the first instance of the job number and returns the information from that line, for all subsequent instances of that job number. I am at a complete loss on how to fix this. I don't even know if `VLOOKUP` can do what I am wanting.

This isn't my actual spreadsheet, I recreated the concept for privacy, but this example is my base spreadsheet that I want to pull info from. Column A is job numbers, column B is City, Column C is Status, Column D is Date 1, Column E is Updated, Column F is Permit Needed, Column G is Date 2, Column H is Date 3, and Column I is Date 4.
[image]

I am using column A, the job number, as the lookup criteria to pull in Date 1, Date 2, and Date 4. This is the formula I am currently using:

`=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'[permitting numbers.xlsx]Sheet3'!$A$2:$D$14,4,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(A2,'[permitting numbers.xlsx]Sheet3'!$A$2:$D$14,4,FALSE),"")`

I have tried it with and without the $. It doesn't work how I need it to either way. This is how my report looks with that formula. I included the city just to demonstrate how a job number can appear more than once, but I don't actually need that on my report.

[image]

I have googled every thing I can think of, but I can't find a solution to return different information for each row that a job number appears.

This is what I want the report to look like:
[image]

If anyone can help I would REALLY appreciate it, this has been driving me crazy.

Comment: Do you have access to `=FILTER()` ? this will return (spill) all instances at once in Office 365 or Excel 2021; all repeated lines and all columns at once.

Comment: Or something like this? give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: Judging by your screenshots, you don't want to lookup, but show all data, excluding certain columns. Would this be what you're after? `=CHOOSECOLS(A1:I14,1,2,4,7,9)` or older Excel: `=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX($A$1:$I$14,ROW($A$1:$I$14),{1,2,4,7,9}),ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1)),"")` entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: You can use an index and an aggregate to pick the right row.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in a new sheet:

| Job | City | Status | Date 1 |  | Rows count |  | Job | City | Date 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1223 | Boston | Complete | 45244 |  | =IF(COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTA(H:H)>0,"More rows","Ok") |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H2)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H2),COUNTIF($H$2:H2,H2))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H2),COUNTIF($H$2:H2,H2)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H2),COUNTIF($H$2:H2,H2)))) |
| 1223 | Chicago | In Progress |  |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H3)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H3),COUNTIF($H$2:H3,H3))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H3),COUNTIF($H$2:H3,H3)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H3),COUNTIF($H$2:H3,H3)))) |
| 1233 | Seattle | Complete |  |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H4)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H4),COUNTIF($H$2:H4,H4))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H4),COUNTIF($H$2:H4,H4)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H4),COUNTIF($H$2:H4,H4)))) |
| 1123 | Boston | Not Started | 45250 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H5)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H5),COUNTIF($H$2:H5,H5))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H5),COUNTIF($H$2:H5,H5)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H5),COUNTIF($H$2:H5,H5)))) |
| 1223 | Boston | Not Started | 45261 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H6)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H6),COUNTIF($H$2:H6,H6))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H6),COUNTIF($H$2:H6,H6)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H6),COUNTIF($H$2:H6,H6)))) |
| 1234 | San Diego | Complete | 45259 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H7)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H7),COUNTIF($H$2:H7,H7))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H7),COUNTIF($H$2:H7,H7)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H7),COUNTIF($H$2:H7,H7)))) |
| 1224 | Chicago | Complete | 45258 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H8)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H8),COUNTIF($H$2:H8,H8))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H8),COUNTIF($H$2:H8,H8)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H8),COUNTIF($H$2:H8,H8)))) |
| 1123 | San Diego | In Progress | 45265 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H9)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H9),COUNTIF($H$2:H9,H9))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H9),COUNTIF($H$2:H9,H9)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H9),COUNTIF($H$2:H9,H9)))) |
| 1244 | Seattle | In Progress | 45273 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H10)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H10),COUNTIF($H$2:H10,H10))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H10),COUNTIF($H$2:H10,H10)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H10),COUNTIF($H$2:H10,H10)))) |
| 1235 | Boston | Not Started |  |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H11)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H11),COUNTIF($H$2:H11,H11))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H11),COUNTIF($H$2:H11,H11)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H11),COUNTIF($H$2:H11,H11)))) |
| 1236 | Seattle | In Progress | 45294 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H12)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H12),COUNTIF($H$2:H12,H12))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H12),COUNTIF($H$2:H12,H12)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H12),COUNTIF($H$2:H12,H12)))) |
| 1225 | Chicago | Complete | 44929 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H13)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H13),COUNTIF($H$2:H13,H13))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H13),COUNTIF($H$2:H13,H13)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H13),COUNTIF($H$2:H13,H13)))) |
| 1233 | Boston | In Progress | 45278 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H14)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H14),COUNTIF($H$2:H14,H14))) | =IF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H14),COUNTIF($H$2:H14,H14)))="","",INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H14),COUNTIF($H$2:H14,H14)))) |

On the left, the fake original data. On the right, the report. In the middle, a formula that checks if you need more row in the report. This solution will sort the list by job ID.

Then again: if you want just to report the list as it is while "cutting off" unwanted columns, you can use something like this:

| Job | City | Status | Date 1 |  | Rows count |  | Job | City | Date 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1223 | Boston | Complete | 45244 |  | =IF(COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTA(H:H)>0,"More rows","Ok") |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H2)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H2),COUNTIF($H$2:H2,H2))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J2),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1223 | Chicago | In Progress |  |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H3)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H3),COUNTIF($H$2:H3,H3))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J3),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1233 | Seattle | Complete |  |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H4)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H4),COUNTIF($H$2:H4,H4))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J4),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1123 | Boston | Not Started | 45250 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H5)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H5),COUNTIF($H$2:H5,H5))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J5),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1223 | Boston | Not Started | 45261 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H6)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H6),COUNTIF($H$2:H6,H6))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J6),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1234 | San Diego | Complete | 45259 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H7)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H7),COUNTIF($H$2:H7,H7))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J7),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1224 | Chicago | Complete | 45258 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H8)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H8),COUNTIF($H$2:H8,H8))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J8),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1123 | San Diego | In Progress | 45265 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H9)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H9),COUNTIF($H$2:H9,H9))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J9),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1244 | Seattle | In Progress | 45273 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H10)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H10),COUNTIF($H$2:H10,H10))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J10),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1235 | Boston | Not Started |  |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H11)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H11),COUNTIF($H$2:H11,H11))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J11),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1236 | Seattle | In Progress | 45294 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H12)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H12),COUNTIF($H$2:H12,H12))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J12),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1225 | Chicago | Complete | 44929 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H13)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H13),COUNTIF($H$2:H13,H13))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J13),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |
| 1233 | Boston | In Progress | 45278 |  |  |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,A:A,ROWS($H$2:H14)) | =INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=H14),COUNTIF($H$2:H14,H14))) | =INDEX($A:$D,ROWS($H$1:J14),IF(MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0)="","",MATCH(J$1,$1:$1,0))) |