# Simple top 3 scores from an array to textfield

Tags: arrays, sorting, actionscript-3, textfield

How to make top 3 scores from an array to the 3 different text fields and sort them highest to lowest scores? My code:

```
var top3Array:Array = [];

var totalScore = int((numeratorCounter/denominatorCounter)*100)/100;

fucntion scoreBoard(): void{
    top3Array.sortOn("totalScore");
    for(i:int = 0, i < 3; i++)
    {
        count1.text = String(count);
        score1.text = String(top3Array[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: See this without vba: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700 give it a vote if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, this one is for Excel. I would like to use a simple array in an actionscript 3.0.

Comment: I know, but it may give you an idea.

Comment: I do not know about this... any ideas than this?

Comment: What is the content of **top3Array**?

Comment: An empty array. When all 4 lives lost, it's game over, then, the score will add to an array. E.g. "score > score1"," score < score1 and score > score2" and score < score2 and score > score3.

Comment: @IsaacYeapJieLing Please, elaborate. Do you ask us how to display an empty array? Probably not. So, I repeat my question: what is the content of the **top3Array**?

Answer (score 0):

Its a little unclear from your question but it sounds like you want to add all of your scores to an array, take the top 3 and display them in some text fields?

As @Organis mentioned, the contents of your array does determine what kind of sort you would need to perform.

If the scores array just contains a list of numbers then you need only use the .sort() function rather than .sortOn()

On the assumption that each score is pushed to an array named allScores each time the player dies you could use code similar to this:

```
// All of the scores
const allScores:Array = [24, 10, 16, 28, 5, 29];

// Sort scores into descending numeric order.
const sortedScores:Array = allScores.sort(Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);
// >> 29,28,24,16,10,5

// Get the first 3 elements of the array - i.e. the 3 highest numbers.
const top3scores:Array = sortedScores.slice(0, 3);
// >> 29,28,24

// Set the text fields' contents to the top scores.
score1.text = top3scores[0];
score2.text = top3scores[1];
score3.text = top3scores[2];
```