# Problems with Index Match Array returning duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-2016, index-match

I'm attempting to return the column name for the three lowest values in a set. At the moment if two values are the same it is duplicating and returning the first value, which I don't want. I need it to return three unique column names with the smallest values.

The values are inputted in row 6  but I want a list in O that returns the corresponding value in row 5 for the lowest three scores without duplicates.

The formulas I have tried are '

```
{=INDEX(E5:L5, MATCH(SMALL(E6:L6,{1;2;3}), E6:L6,0))}
```

and the following which gave me an N/A error.

`=INDEX(E5:L5, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A$1, E6:L6)+IF(E6:L6<>"", 1, 0), 0))`

I'm currently using Excel 2016 so TRANSPOSE/SORT didn't work for me either. I'm at a loss.

The values are inputted between E6:L6 and I need the returning values to be in an array from O10.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhQjn.png)

Crossposted: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1416581-index-match-array-returning-duplicate-values.html

Comment: `Aggregate()` may help. Post few of your sample data then show your desired output.

Comment: Thank you. Added the link to my original post.

Comment: excel 2016 have Filter Function or not ?

Comment: @Sunny `Excel-2016` doesn't have `FILTER()` function.

Comment: Have a look at this and give it a vote if it helps, it should do : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a "Helper Row" somewhere on your worksheet

```
AE6: =COUNTIF(E6:$L$6,E6)-1
```

and `fill right` to `AL6`

For largest 3 numbers:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX($E$5:$L$5,,MATCH({1,2,3},RANK.EQ($E6:$L6,$E6:$L6,0)+$AE6:$AL6,0)))
```

For smallest 3 numbers:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX($E$5:$L$5,,MATCH({1,2,3},RANK.EQ($E6:$L6,$E6:$L6,1)+$AE6:$AL6,0)))
```

If Excel 2016 does not have dynamic arrays, you can either:

- Enter it as an array (ctrl-shift-enter) across the three rows
- Use the INDEX function to return each individual element

***Counts***
[image]

***Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @Dreadpiraterai Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

For Excel-2016 try the following array formula-

```
=INDEX($E$5:$L$5,1,SMALL(IF(($E$6:$L$6>=MIN($E$6:$L$6))*($E$6:$L$6<=SMALL($E$6:$L$6,3)),COLUMN($E$6:$L$6)-COLUMN($D$5),""),ROW(1:1)))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but it is just returning SD (first column) across all three return values

Comment: Did you press `CRTL+SHIFT+ENTER` after putting formula to cell?

Comment: Yes. But SD is shown on all three cells that I selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant one but works

Presume that E23:L23 is the column header range
E28:L28 is the data range

Cell O25 : `=INDEX(A23:L23,1,(SMALL(E28:L28+COLUMN(E28:L28)/100,{1,2,3,4})-SMALL(E28:L28,{1,2,3,4}))*100)`

and drag down to O28

Take care that index range start from column A!

This is for the first four but this you can expand or truncate with the array {1....4}. If more than 100 columns are used change the 100 value to 1000.

[image]