# excel name top value based on the ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have LIST the employee ID (repeated), the job position name, and the duration the employee worked in this position.

I managed to extract the longest duration an employee worked based on the user ID.
this example (Original list +1700 row)

| Employee ID | Job Title | Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13993 | HT | 15 |
| 13993 | BM | 1 |
| 14614 | TS | 21 |
| 15378 | BM | 21 |
| 16003 | TS | 1 |
| 17201 | BM | 1 |
| 17292 | BM | 3 |
| 17313 | HT | 1 |
| 17313 | BM | 10 |

i use this formulas for MaxDay

```
=MAXIFS(DAYS,ID,A2(ID))
```

and this formulas for job Title

```
INDEX(JobTitle,MATCH(MAXIFS(DAYS,ID,A2(ID)),Days,0))
```

However, when I try to extract max job positions that the employee worked in, it doesn't work

result

| id | MaxDay | job Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13993 | 15 | OM |

The problem is that the job title appears as "OM", while the correct is "HT" and this employee has never worked as "OM"
Any solution?

[image]

Comment: Put your data and expected results into your question instead of an image

Comment: How do you deal with duplicates? Check this out and give it a vote if it helps> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One better alternative using the `Dynamic Array Formulas` in Excel :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(x, SORT(A2:C10,{1,3},{1,-1}), CHOOSECOLS(XLOOKUP(E2, TAKE(x,,1),DROP(x,,1)),2,1))
```

---

- Using `SORT()` function sort the data by `Emp ID` & `Days`
- Using `XLOOKUP()` function to return the `Max Days` & `Job Title`.

---

Or,

[image]

---

If one needs to return multiple records:

```
=LET(x, SORT(A2:C10,{1,3},{1,-1}), INDEX(x,XMATCH(E2:E3,TAKE(x,,1)),{3,2}))
```

---

As per OP's Comments:

> *Thank you for the help; I really appreciate it. The problem is that*
> *the Office 2019 version does not support those formulas :(*

---

[image]

---

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(E2&"|"&F2,$A$2:$A$10&"|"&$C$2:$C$10,0))
```

---

Comment: Thank you for the help; I really appreciate it. The problem is that the Office 2019 version does not support those formulas :( .

Comment: Updated as per Excel Version!

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your formulas to work at all. What is A2(ID)?

I'm assuming you have this information in an Excel table and you can refer to the columns by name, in which case the formula should be

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAXIFS([Days],[[ID]],[@[ID]]),C:C,0),1)
```

If that is the wrong assumption, but I assume your data starts with the header 'ID' in Cell A1 then the formula should be

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),C:C,0),1)
```

I built this formula in stages by adding helper columns D,E,F

```
Column1=MAXIFS([Days],[[ID]],[@[ID]])
Column2=MATCH([@Column1],C:C,0)
Column3=INDEX(B:B,[@Column2],1)
```

I then built up the final formula by replacing the `[@Column2]` in Column3 with the formula from Column2, then replacing the `[@Column1]` that was now in Column3 with the formula from Column1. Delete the helper columns