# How can I produce the top 4 earliest dates from a column of dates in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of dates, and I want to produce automatically the top 4 earliest dates and the rows they belong to. Example:

| Unit | Date Received |
| --- | --- |
| Unit 1 | 19-Jan-24 |
| Unit 2 | 8-Jan-23 |
| Unit 3 | 9-Nov-23 |
| Unit 4 | 17-Jan-24 |
| Unit 5 | 19-Jan-24 |

I would want to take the top 4 earliest dates in the order they appear, in this case it would look like this:

| Unit | Date Received |
| --- | --- |
| Unit 2 | 8-Jan-23 |
| Unit 3 | 9-Nov-23 |
| Unit 4 | 17-Jan-24 |
| Unit 1 | 19-Jan-24 |

I already attempted to use a MIN formula, and that did exactly as expected, but I haven't been able to think of a way to bring the second earliest, or the third earliest dates.

Comment: Why Unit 1 and not Unit 5? Both have same date

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have multiple matches for each of the four most recent dates:

- Most recent is 19-Jan
- Also having 2 on the 17th and 1 on the 16th and 18th

How do you tie-break between the duplicates?

If you want to return all of those, you can use:

```
=VSTACK($A$1:$B$1,FILTER($A$2:$B$9, $B$2:$B$9>= LARGE(UNIQUE($B$2:$B$9),4)))
```

[image]

Or, if you wanted it sorted by dates, as pointed out by @P.b.:

`=VSTACK($A$1:$B$1,SORT(FILTER($A$2:$B$9, $B$2:$B$9>= LARGE(UNIQUE($B$2:$B$9),4)),2))`

[image]

Comment: You could wrap the filter in SORT, so it's sorted from oldest to newest date: `=SORT(FILTER($A$2:$B$9, $B$2:$B$9>= LARGE(UNIQUE($B$2:$B$9),4)),2)`

Comment: @P.b Thanks. I had overlooked that part of the request.

Comment: I think he needed it like you posted: *"in order they appear"* (not sure if he means appear in the data, or in time) but I think it makes more sense if you select them by aging, that sorting the result by aging gives more insight.

Comment: @P.b That is the order he shows in his example, but his question is confusing. `Top4 earliest` Should this be the most recent or the oldest? `Order they appear` In the data or by time? And he doesn't say anything about what to do with ties, in his example he ignores the last entry which is a tie. Hopefully he'll post back and clarify.

Comment: Well I'd go for your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

`=TAKE(SORT(A2:B6,2,1),4)`

It first sorts by the date and then returns the top 4 rows.

[image]

Comment: We were posting answer almost same time.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula-

```
=TAKE(SORT(A2:B6,2),4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And here is another possibility using small() and index() with match():

[image]

Formulae so you can copy & paste:

```
INDEX($A$3:$A$7,MATCH(E3,$B$3:$B$7,0))

SMALL(B$3:B$7,C3)
```

The dates can be formatted long - I left them as short.

If you need to deal with duplicates then look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700